# How to typeset "TikZ"?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know I can use the macros `\TeX` and `\LaTeX` for typesetting the names of TeX and LaTeX (including the necessary vertical alignment trick).

But how am I supposed to typeset "TikZ"? (I am asking because I'd like to mention TikZ in the Colophon of a book).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Look at the [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). It’s typeset as `Ti\textit{k}Z` …

You may create a new command if you would like to use it more than one time. If you use [`xspace`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace), it takes care of the following space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\TikZ}{Ti\textit{k}Z\xspace}

\begin{document}
\TikZ with a following space and without \TikZ.
\end{document}
```

<sub>For further reading: [Drawbacks of xspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/4918)</sub>

As said in the the comments, there are some other possible definitions:

1. `Ti\emph{k}Z`, which will have an italic `k` in upright context and an upright `k` in italic context. So the `k` is always emphasizes, which may satisfies the source of the name “TikZ ist *kein* Zeichenprogramm” (TikZ is *no* drawing software), where the word `kein` should be emphasized.
2. `\textup{Ti\textit{k}Z}` will produce the version with upright `T`, `i` and `Z` and italic `k` in all cases. This may be preferable, when the original appearance should be kept for the whole document.

Comment: In the sources of the pgfmanual (/pgf/doc/generic/pgf/macros/pgfmanual-en-macros.tex) : `\def\tikzname{Ti\emph{k}Z}` possible    `\newcommand*\Tikz{Ti\textit kZ}`

Comment: It’s on the title page, page 3, 19, 20, 21, … and many more ;-)

Comment: Ooh -- of course! Use the source... :-)

Comment: @Altermundus: I prefer `\textit` to be sure that it’s italic

Comment: Yes  I gave the macro found in pgfmanual-en-macros.tex. It's strange to use two different definitions ...

Comment: If you want to be sure that the `k` is italic, you might want to ensure that the `T`, `i`, and `Z` are upright, as in `\newcommand*\TikZ{\textup{Ti\textit kZ}}`.

Comment: I would also use @NieldeBeaudrap 's suggestion if for example someone uses it in an italic or emphasized environment just to be sure it is typeset correctly.

Comment: All this discussion in the comments happen because TikZ has no \TikZ macro defined. What a shame. I refuse to create a macro that should be provided by the package itself. I will just write TikZ. :-(