# \xspace and hyphenation

Tags: spacing, hyphenation, xspace

I was considering to use xspace for some common standard terms in my document, like:

```
\newcommand{\ring}{my secret ring\xspace}
```

I am now wondering, if hyphenation gets it right, when I do this?

```
\ring{}s
```

#### Notes

That asked, I realize the existance of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/24158 and I probably should not use xspace at all and just use the normal definition, in which case I hope the hyphenation gets it right always.

I also possibly should really define more terms instead of trickyly appending to them. But german has a bunch of postfixes, so that's not funny either.

Not using a macro IS an option. I am trying to explore my viable options.

Comment: Well, it's difficult for TeX to hyphenate "rings". But `\xspace` has no influence in hyphenation.

Comment: Why does no one ever believe me when I tell them not to use my packages:-)

Comment: @egreg - ring was bad chosen, accepted. I just couldn't think, of something simpler today.

Comment: @David Carlisle - *G* I actually linked your posting, where you basicly recommend against your package. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the proof that hyphenation is not influenced by `\xspace`; `\hspace{0pt}` allows hyphenation of the first word, the width of 0pt forces LaTeX to hyphenate as much as it can.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\super}{supercalifragilistic\xspace}
\newcommand{\superB}{supercalifragilisti\xspace}
\begin{document}
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}
\super{}expialidocious
\superB{}cexpialidocious}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I don't see how `\xspace` can be of help in this case; you *need* to add an empty group if a suffix follow, which seems to be a frequent case. Without `\xspace`, `\super expialidocious` or `\super{}expialidocious` would give the same result. And for the cases where no suffix is present, adding `{}` at the end doesn't seem a big deal.

Comment: If I have to use the version with suffix only rarely, `xspace` might make things easier.