# How to remove the space after an exclamation point

Tags: spacing

I am creating a document about a project whose name is "Go for it!" with an exclamation point. I am fairly new to Latex, but I figured that there should be a command to print the project name, with the exclamation mark and everything. So I did:

```
\newcommand{\goforit}{Go for it!}
```

The problem is the exclamation mark, since Latex prints a space after it, and in case I want to say "Go for it!, due to its awesomeness[...]", it will print a space before the comma, which is undesirable.

From what I've read, I can append "\ " to it, but that will indeed still print a space before the comma.

Comment: latex does not add space after `!` (and xspace does not remove space) If you are getting a space you must have a space in the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `\xspace` macro of the eponymous package. Consider the following MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\gfi}{Go for it!\xspace}
\begin{document}
\gfi Yes, \gfi, right now.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, nothing's ever perfect, and that applies to `\xspace` as well. To read up on some of its potential shortcomings (which I generally find too dreadful), you may want to read the posting [Drawbacks of xspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/5001).

Comment: Xspace should not be relevant here, the OP said latex was printing space... (despite the fact that it's accepted answer:-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did the `xspace` got the right answer here :)

The answer for those who got the same problem is to add a backslash after the exclamation or question marks if they do not end a sentence.

i.e.
`Go for it!\`

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please avoid external links that could break in the future. An answer like this one can very well stand on its own. Thank you.