# Combining dashes from babel with xspace

Tags: spacing, hyphenation, babel, xspace

Assume we have some mathematical object that is used in formulae as well as in "natural" language (in my case, complexity classes). When defining a macro for such an object, I like to use `\xspace` so that spacing works as expected in all circumstances.

That has been working fine for me until I discovered the nice hyphenation control features of `babel`; `\xspace` seems to conflict with these:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\NP}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{NP}}\xspace}

\begin{document}
  $L \in \NP$, daher foo.\\
  $L$ ist in \NP. \\
  $L$ ist \NP"=vollständig.
\end{document}
```

The combination with `"=` -- which would imply the breaking/hyphenation desired in this case -- leads to an obviously wrong result:

[image]

I [notice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace) that I have probably been overusing `\xspace` but I don't know a different way. How can I fix this?

Comment: Just don't use `\xspace`; `\NP` is math, so `$\NP$` will avoid all problems with spaces in text.

Comment: @egreg I thought the purpose of `\ensuremath` is to avoid having to use math delimiters in such cases? I have been enjoying being able to drop them. :/ Nevertheless, adding dollars in just these contentious places *does* solve the issue (even with `\xspace`). Maybe add an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package `xspace` checks the next token to decide, whether to set or suppress a space. New recognized tokens for omitting the space can be added by `\xspaceaddexceptions`. The next token is expanded and each expansion step checked. This can be used for `"=` that consists of two tokens. At some expansion step it expands to one token `\ngerman@sh@"@=`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}[2004/12/07]

\expandafter\xspaceaddexceptions\expandafter{%
  \csname ngerman@sh@"@=@\endcsname
}

\newcommand{\NP}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{NP}}\xspace}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  $L \in \NP$, daher foo.\\
  $L$ ist in \NP. \\
  $L$ ist \NP"=vollständig.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Nice, though something seems to be off. Adding this one rule seems to add exceptions for other dashes like `"~` (or custom-made `"/`), and also gibberish like `"(`. Does it only require a `"` and then some other character? The rule does not seem to apply to `"`. (The version parameter for `xspace` does not seem to be neccessary?)

Comment: @Raphael: Older versions of `xspace` do not provide `\xspaceaddexceptions`.

Comment: @Raphael: The same trick also works for other shorthands: `"~` is supported by `\expandafter\xspaceaddexceptions\expandafter{\csname ngerman@sh@"@\string~\endcsname}`. Adding the shorthand `"` does not seem a good idea to me. If a word starts with an umlaut, there should be a space before.