# French babel trouble: 1\ier{}, 2\ieme{}, etc

Tags: babel, french

I'm having an issue with French babel. Whenever I use any of the 1`\ier{}`, 2`\ieme{}` and so on [constructs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#French) (to obtain 1<sup>er</sup>, 2<sup>e</sup>, etc.), the spacing following it behaves very strangely.

So, for example, if I use:

- `1\ier asdf` then the output in the PDF will be: "1<sup>er</sup>asdf" (notice the missing space between "<sup>er</sup>" and "asdf")
- `1\ier~asdf` then the output in the PDF will be: "1<sup>er</sup> asdf" (with a protected space in between)
- `1\ier~ asdf` then the output in the PDF will be: "1<sup>er</sup>  asdf" (there are **two** spaces between "<sup>er</sup>" and "asdf", one protected and one normal; can't display properly here because of SE formatting limitations)

I don't want to use `~` every time I need these constructs (2nd and 3rd examples above), so my **question**: Is the first example above a bug or a user error? And what is the proper way to avoid such output glitches?

I'm using TeX Live 2009 on Ubuntu 12.04 (with LyX).

Comment: You should: if "premier" precedes a word, it should remain attached to it.

Comment: @landroni I've moved my comment. "Hard space" is indeed the same as "non-breaking space" in English (our "espace insécable", `~` in TeX), or at least I've learnt it so. As a side effect, `~` avoids any gobbled space that instead may happen between both words. But I don't understand your last remark: in his comment, egreg is suggesting exactly the same thing as me.

Comment: @fpast Right! @ egreg wasn't explicit in his comment. I mistakenly took it to understand that the first example in the question was correct; he was suggesting that the second was correct, with the protected space (as you did).

Comment: @landroni I think you should report it to the `french` package maintainer. It would be a wise thing to at least use `xspace` so that a normal space is inserted when there is no punctuation immediately following the superscript. You would still need to write explicit `~` characters based on context when you need a non-breaking space. But as others said, the output you get is the normal TeX behaviour – but babel French is quite user friendly, and I would not expect this as its normal behaviour (but I use custom commands, so I hadn't noticed it).

Comment: @ienissei See me answer: Daniel Flipo (maintainer of frenchb) recommands to add `xspace` package in order to handle correctly the space in such case.

Comment: Try `1\ier{} asdf` or `1\up{er} asdf` or use the `xspace` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `\usepackage{xspace}`.

According to [the manual of frenchb](http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/frenchb/index.html):

> Il est recommandé de profiter des avantages offerts par l’extension
>   xspace (il suffit d’ajouter \usepackage{xspace} dans le préambule) :
>   les espaces suivant les commandes \ier,. . ., \ieres, \ieme, \iemes,
>   \fg et \dots seront respectés sans avoir à les forcer par des {} ou
>   des \ .

Comment: Thanks. Apparently `xspace` is being discouraged in some circles: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace .

Comment: Also, it seems that the two recommended usage forms, which avoid unexpected consequences, are: `\ier{}` or `\ier{}~`, as appropriate given the context.

Comment: @landroni `xspace` tries to avoid human errors (to forget \ or {}). And you are right to point out that, in some case, this useful tool could break some code (because it is not easy for an computer to know when you actually doing a mistake). However plenty of packages are coded with the need of `xspace` package ; `frenchb` is one of them. To sum up: if you want to use `frenchb`, you should use `xspace` also (because `frenchb` needs `xspace` to do a good job) : if you do not use any package which needs `xspace` it is better to not use it.

Comment: @landroni About the recommended usage forms, [the manual of frenchb](http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/frenchb/frenchb-doc.pdf) says p.5 "*on dispose aussi de \ier \iere \iers \ieres \ieme \iemes pour 1er, 1re, 1ers, 1res, 2e, 2es.*". So according to the manual, the recommended formating is `1\ier`. Of course, this recommendation assumes you use `xspace`. If you don't, you should prefer `1\ier{}` but it is **not** what is recommended by the author package.

Answer (score 3):

In French, you should always use a hard space between an abbreviation and the following word. For example, have a look at ["Petites leçons de typographie"](http://jacques-andre.fr/faqtypo/lessons.pdf) by Jacques André, page 34. As such, your second case is the right one: "1<sup>er</sup> asdf" (with a protected space in between).

The two others are the [normal behavior](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-xspace) of such (La)TeX commands.

Comment: The [TeX FAQ link](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=xspace) suggests using `1\ier{} asdf` to avoid a "gobbled" space, as does [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#French). Does this mean that the default definition of `\ier{}` is incorrect and does NOT take into account the protected, non-breaking space (`~`) required by French typesetting conventions?

Comment: @landroni Yes and no. No, it does not take into account our typographical conventions. But it can be useful in peculiar cases. For example, in such expressions as `le 1\ier{} de la classe`, no protected space is required following our conventions, to the contrary of `la 1\iere~fois`, `le 1\ier~jour`, etc, but any gobbled space must be avoided all the same. The hard space is necessary only when the abbreviated word refers to the following word.

Comment: Ouch! Could you include this last comment in the answer? It seems that the two recommended usage forms are `1\ier{} asdf` or `1\ier~asdf`, depending on the context; but NOT `1\ier asdf`.

Comment: @landroni Yes, it's what I meant :-). However, it must be said that the contexts where the non-breaking space is necessary happen much more frequently! So my comment was a complement of my anwer, and as such more fit (I think) as a comment.

Comment: @landroni To complete the confusion, you may notice that neither `{}` nor `~` are required in expressions such as `Il y a le 1\ier, et il y a les autres`. The presence of the comma makes `\ier{}` useless and `\ier~` nefast as it introduces an undesired space :-)

Comment: I hesitate to accept your answer since as it stands it feels incomplete (as per my tastes): the `1\ier{} asdf` vs `1\ier~asdf` bit is crucial. :) As for `1\ier,`, the `1\ier{},` is fine but `1\ier~,` will result in a typographical error. So `{}` is not necessary, but `~` is a mistake.

In this sense, it seems to me that the only two recommended usage forms should be: `\ier{}` or `\ier{}~`. The `{}` should be used at all times, to avoid unintended behaviour.

Comment: But is that good writing to use an abbreviation as a noun, and moreover, the abbraviation of an ordinal adjective?

Comment: @landroni As you said, it depends on the context. I would say that you should use `1\ier~asdf` when `asdf`'s meaning is directly related to `1\ier`, and `1\ier{}`in all other cases where a space is required directly after `1\ier`.

Comment: @fpast Other than more typing involved, are there any potential drawbacks with using `\ier{}~` instead?

Comment: @Bernard I don't think so either, and yet it is what the writer desires sometimes (I must often typeset other's texts and follow their whims). In this case I prefer to limit the damages. :-)

Comment: @landroni No, but I wouldn't see the point in doing this.

Comment: @fpast Well, I was vaguely planning to come up with a [LyX module](http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/Modules) for all these constructs, and I wanted to make sure that `\ier{}` as a baseline construct is most appropriate, and that adding a protected space `\ier{}~` wouldn't break things for users.

Comment: @fpast I would write *Il y a le premier, et il y a les autres*.

Comment: @egreg Me too in fact, but as I said not every French-speaking person is keen to follow « le bon usage de la langue française »…

Answer (score 1):

**Changed**:
Add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\apptocmd{\ier}{~}{}{}
\apptocmd{\iere}{~}{}{}
```

and similarly for each abbreviated french ordinal. Curiously, `frenchb` lacks commands for the abbreviations  of second(e)(s).

Comment: No `xspace` please, it's such a pain for the editors if they have to edit your work at any time! Even the package author is not at all happy about its existance.

Comment: I suspect that second(e)(s) are covered by 2\ieme{} and 2\iemes{}. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#French .

Comment: @tohecz: But what to do then? Anyway Frenchb.ldf uses it, but for some reason it has no effect. Isn't it more painful for an editor to have lots of ~ in the document body?

Comment: @Bernard See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace

Comment: @landroni: "Second" and "deuxième" are not synonyms: Writing "second" implies there is no "third".

Comment: @tohecz: I modified my answer to take you remark into account.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution breaks things if you use `\ier{}` or if you have `\ier.` constructs in your LaTeX source. (See discussion in the other answer.)

Comment: This is not an correct answer: frenchb works fine, it just needed `xspace` package. See my answer.

Comment: @ppr: I know that. It's something I had added first, but I tried to answer to @tohecz's objection to the use of `xspace`.