# Is there a command to correctly abbreviate the French ordinal « second »?

Tags: acronyms, french

I cannot find any command available in a LaTeX package to produce the abbreviated version of the words second/seconde/seconds/secondes, when dealing with ordinals in French, as I would use for other ordinals like `3\ieme`, for example. So far, I ended up defining

```
\newcommand{\cond}{\up{d}}
```

in my header, as suggested [here](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d222417/autres-langages/autres-langages/latex/mise-forme/abreviation-second-seconde/#post1425498). This produces the following rendering, for `2\cond` in a beamer presentation for instance, which is fine:

[image]

But, first, I'm not quite sure then that it will **always** be consistently rendered with the other abbreviations for other (French) ordinals in the same document. Also, what I am looking for is not having to redefine this command in every single LaTeX file of mine, to make the call consistent with `\ieme` for the other ordinals. In 2014, it was pointed out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161962/117801) that LaTeX would lack the commands for these abbreviations. Is it still true?

Comment: And I am not talking about the classical debate for French people about when to use best the words « deuxième » or « second » (see - in French - https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second#Adjectif_num%C3%A9ral_ordinal). ;)

Comment: The `fmtcount` package with `babel` will do this for you I think. It provides an `\ordinal` macro.

Comment: @alanmunn, as far as I undesrtood, this will yield « 2e » in French, and not « 2nd ».

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your goal.  `2\up{d}` is the same number of characters as `\second`.  I could see a desire to have `2\up{d}` automatically show up in an `enumerate` environment, but that doesn't seem to be what you're wanting.  Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by "self-defined".  You talk about (re)defining this in all of your LaTeX files, which seems unavoidable (unless you have a personal package you've included everywhere), but then on an answer you remark about an argumentless command to produce the abbreviation.  How are you intending to use this in a document?

Comment: @Teepeemm, I have edited my question to answer your question. I hope this is clearer now. My main point is that I want all the commands to be consistent with one another (for my mind, at least), and that it would not be a hack of mine, but something consistently provided by one package (or even several of them, if needed).

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}

In French, the correct abbreviations are: 2\up{d}, 2\up{de} and 2\ieme.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it is not « 2nd » but « 2d ». I have corrected my question so. Still, I guess you claim there is no argumentless command to produce this abbreviation, then.

Comment: +1, but the `$` seems unnecessary and doesn’t give the desired result if `realscripts` is loaded.

Comment: @Thérèse: You are right. I will suppress the `$`.

Comment: @Olivier: Indeed. I think that you have to create your own macro...

Comment: @Olivier: I would abbreviate « second » into 2\ieme as  the output of 2\up{d} is rather hard to read: something like « deux-d ». What is the point of insisting about the fact that there is no third? Btw, that is the reason why no specific macro is provided in babel-french for second/seconde/seconds/secondes.

Comment: @DanielFlipo: The fact that the use of the adjective « second » leads to no possible existence of a third element is an urban legend (see [this post](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/QDL029) and [that post](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/second-deuxieme)). Also, I am not judging the hardness to read it, since this is [the normal way to abbreviate it](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicateur_ordinal#Fran%C3%A7ais). In any case, I am just trying to insert a sentence using « second degré » in its abbreviated form, and I obviously cannot choose to change « second » to « deuxième ».

Comment: @DanielFlipo: By the way, I would really be interested in some source of yours (any documentation, email, whatever) about the reason(s) of the decision not to provide such a macro in babel-french, since this word does exist and sometimes cannot be replaced (as in the example I have just cited, within the French educational context).

Comment: @Oliver: I have not been able to find any example of 2\up{d} mentioned in any typographic guide I know of… it's up to you to define a macro for it if  you need it.