# Proper spacing with ellipsis and xspace

Tags: xspace, ellipsis

Really a simple enough question, but I haven't found an answer, so … is there any straightforward way of making the spacing adjustments of `ellipsis.sty` work with `xspace`? The package itself has an `xspace` option, which adds the command to all occurrences of `dots`, but this seems to come in the way of the spacing, so one needs to use `\dots\␣` anyway. I'm not committed to using `ellipsis.sty` – what I'd like is just proper spacing (for some definition of proper `;)`), along with `xspace`, or some similar mechanism.

**Added example**

Here's a minimal example to illustrate the behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[xspace]{ellipsis}
\begin{document}
\noindent
x \dots x\\
x … x\\
x \dots\ x\\
x …\ x
\end{document}
```

This also includes Unicode ellipses, which are part of my motivation – the ability to typeset externally generated text directly, without inserting explicit spacing commands.

Here's how it looks:

[image: With xspace]

Here's how it looks without the `xspace` option:

[image]

And here, without `ellipsis.sty` altogether:

[image]

The spacing I want is the one I get with both `ellipsis.sty` and the explicit `\␣`. But I'd like to get it automatically – at least for the Unicode ellipsis character. It's less crucial that I make it happen for the `\dots` command.

I guess maybe I shouldn't rely on `xspace`. Is there any “obviously correct” way to get the proper(?) spacing after the Unicode ellipsis character, though?

Comment: You should a minimal compilable example (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document`) which we can compile and see the exact problem you say in our computers.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620