# Shorter space after ellipsis

Tags: ellipsis

MWE

[image]

Is this true? expected? typographically correct? If it should be fixed, how? I've browsed related questions but found no answers.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[text={2.1in,4in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{microtype} % since it's in my document

\begin{document}

In this sentence the space after the ellipsis \dots seems
noticeably shorter than the space before it. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: there's no space after `\dots` because spaces after a control sequence are ignored (except as needed to recognize the end of the control sequence).  the usual recommendation is to insert a "slash space" after `\dots\ ` to get an ordinary (as opposed to end-of-sentence) space.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That explains why it happens. I'll go with the explicit `\` since it's not needed often in my document. But `\dots` should deal with the typographic question automaticaly. If you post as an answer I'll accept so the question won't stay unanswered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[barbara's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272242/) explains why this happens and offers some advice on how to address it. I have to say, I'm pretty sure I'm wildly inconsistent about how I handle this.

Here's a comparison:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Some words \dots after the beginning.

Some words \textellipsis after the beginning.

Some words \dots\ after the beginning.

Some words \textellipsis\ after the beginning.
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: comparison with and without forced space]

While the lack of space in the first two cases looks odd, the second two don't look quite right to me either because the space *after* the ellipsis now *exceeds* that before it.

As I understand it, this is because space equal to that between the dots is added after the final dot to ensure that any following punctuation is correctly spaced:

```
Do you know some words \dots?

Do you know some words \textellipsis?
```

produces:

[image: spaced punctuation]

which seems reasonable. When `\` is added after the ellipsis, the additional space is added to the space already there.

If you want even spacing around the ellipsis, the `ellipsis` package offers a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ellipsis}
\begin{document}

Some words \dots\ after the beginning.

Some words \textellipsis\ after the beginning.

Do you know some words \dots?

Do you know some words \textellipsis?
\end{document}
```

produces balanced spacing in both kinds of case:

[image: adjusted spacing]

But if, like me, you are horribly inconsistent about this, you might hope the package would solve the problem automatically.

According to the documentation, you should be able to do just this using the option `xspace`. In that case, you are supposed to be able to type `\dots whatever` and have everything work. However, when I try that, the spacing after the ellipsis is again larger than that before it, although the effect is less pronounced than without the package.

That is,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xspace]{ellipsis}
\begin{document}

Some words \dots\ after the beginning.

Some words \textellipsis\ after the beginning.

Some words \dots after the beginning.

Some words \textellipsis after the beginning.

Do you know some words \dots?

Do you know some words \textellipsis?
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: maladjusted spacing]

*rather than*

[image: expected output]

So I'm not sure this option works quite as intended....

**EDIT** Moreover, [`xspace`'s author recommends avoiding the package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620).

Comment: May be using `…` (unicode ellipsis) solves this inconsistency with spaces and more :) Just load `inputenc` and declare the unicode character (or even use `newunicodechar`.

Comment: @Manuel I don't think so... Did you see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175348/proper-spacing-with-ellipsis-and-xspace)? Or are you suggesting something without `xspace`?

Comment: I meant that the fact that `…` is not `\dots` the next space is not gobbled, so it can be controlled much easier, rather than use `xspace`.

Comment: @Manuel But then you need to add a matching amount of space when the next character is a punctuation mark i.e. to match the space between the dots. I'm not sure this is more easily controlled.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, but I fear to repeat David's mistakes ;).

Comment: Okey, I'm not saying anything extraordinary just that `\usepackage{ellipsis}` and `…` work more or less like `\usepackage[xspace]{ellipsis}` and `\dots` with the *benefit that you are not using `xspace`*; and with the power to change anything at the end if you want to nitpick (see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179336/21930) and the linked answers). No need to extend the comments

Comment: By the way, if only me is writing comments, you don't need the `@Manuel` part :)

Comment: I thought you did for comments on answers, but maybe I'm just deluded about that.

Comment: No need if only one is writting comments :)

Answer (score 14):

there's no space after `\dots` because spaces after a control sequence are ignored (except as needed to recognize the end of the control sequence).

the usual recommendation is to insert a "slash space" after `\dots\` to get an ordinary (as opposed to end-of-sentence) space.  however, if `\dots` really does end a sentence, then entering it as `\dots{}` or `{\dots}` will trigger the end-of-sentence space.

`\dots` can appear in contexts where it's not possible to determine whether it should be followed by a space in the output, or indeed, what kind of space.

**edit:**
after reading the excellent [answer by cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272256/579), i decided to do a little digging.  the definitions of
`\dots` in both plain tex and latex are somewhat convoluted, but the
point about the extra space being added to `\dots` (and `\textellipsis`}
to ensure good spacing before another punctuation mark is right on.

what i discovered, though, is that, even though `\dots` and `\textellipsis`
share this feature in text mode, `\ldots` (on which both are based) is free
from it, as shown in this simple demonstration.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\fbox{.}\quad\fbox{.\,.}\quad\fbox{\dots}\quad\fbox{$\ldots$}
\end{document}
```

[image: images of different boxed dots]

so, if your goal is absolutely symmetrical spaces before and after the
dots, use `\ldots` directly.  (in other words, don't be la{tex}zy.)

on another tack, in a comment someone asked about using the unicode
character (U+2026) directly.  when implemented in a font, that character
is usually designed (in most fonts that i've seen) with tighter spacing than
provided by `\dots` and would look out of place in most tex settings.