# Make macro obey spacing or lack thereof

Tags: macros

I made this simple macro:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\newcommand\Q{\textbf{Q}}

\begin{document}
I like to type my \Q's in bold quickly, but sometimes I also end my line with \Q. 
This doesn't have it's intended effect.
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to tell the macro to check the space (or character) ahead and obey it as if I typed `\textbf{Q}` normally? I'd like it to behave normally regardless of whether there's a dot (.) or a whitespace ( ) ahead.

Comment: No the space is the delimiter of the macro name. There is xspace but see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/1090

Comment: I just get in the habit of typing its use case as `{\Q}` in my document.  Then it acts the way you want.

Comment: `{\Q}` would disable the automatic italic correction insertion that is added by `\text...` commands  (or at least it would disable it on the right but not on the left) probably more of an issue with `\textit` than `\texbf` but still....

Comment: Can you add some examples of the input and the desired output as I don't seem to be getting exactly what is desired behavior is.

Comment: @PeterGrill I'd like to see {<bold Q>}{<dot>} instead of {<bold Q>}{<space>}{>dot>} when using \Q. That's all I ask for.

Comment: Please add these examples to the question.  With the `xspace` solution `\Q.` does produce `{<bold Q>}{<dot>}` without a space,  but so did the MWE you had posted originally.  Does this one example cover all the cases you are considering?

Comment: @PeterGrill Package `xspace` didn't produce the desired result in my document, so I think I'll just go with a 1% less cleaner code of the main document. I could go over each and every case, but I don't think either of us would enjoy it. Thanks for your answers and help :)

Answer (score 1):

Even thought is has sort of become taboo lately, the `xspace` pacakge does that:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand\Q{\textbf{Q}\xspace}

\begin{document}
I like to type my \Q's in bold quickly, but sometimes I also end my line with \Q. 
This doesn't have it's intended effect.

In a sentence \Q works now.
\end{document}
```

Comment: well it does something but it doesn't do what was asked. It is not possible to check if there was space or not; xspace adds space depending on whether there is following punctuation but any space is not seen `\Q .` is the same as `\Q.` as the space is gone before `\Q` is even recognised.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, the subtle weakness of `xspace`… Luckily having `\Q . blah` is bad form :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Hmmm. Wonder if I got into the habit of not reading the question from _someone_ who doesn't think it is fair to read documentation. :-) Guess I am not understanding the question fully.