# Shortcut to writing out long, common, expressions?

Tags: math-mode, macros

I'm writing an astronomy paper and have some symbols and variables which are common throughout. It's becoming cumbersome to write them out each time. Is there a way to create a shortcut of sorts for these? Note, most are in math-mode.

**For example:**
log(Hi)

```
$\log(\textrm{H}\textsc{i})$
```

log(SFR/M*)

```
$\log(\textrm{SFR} / \textrm{M}_{\odot})$
```

Comment: `\def\loghi{\log(\textrm{H}\textsc{i})}`  Then in usage, `$\loghi$`.  Note I left `$` out of the `\def`, to allow it to be used in conjunction with other math; for example, `$\loghi = x$`.

Comment: Note that for non-math defs, for example `\def\rms{root-mean-square}`, its usage in text will usually be `the \rms{} of...`, with the empty braces following, otherwise the succeeding blank gets eaten by the TeX parser.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a job for a \newcommand?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The `xspace` package is very nice to avoid the need for `{}` at every use of a macro defined in such a manner.

Comment: @cslstr Many people say so, but the author of `xspace` isn't so sure: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace

Comment: @AndyClifton Yes, `\newcommand` is "safer" than `\def` in that, if a macro by that name already exists, it will break the compilation, rather than allowing the original definition to be overwritten by the new `\def` (which could cause strange, difficult to debug, errors).  Call it typing laziness on my part.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes RE: `xspace` -- interesting...

Comment: Thanks folks, this is helpful. When I use \loghi in a subtitle however it doesn't capitalise the 'i'.

Comment: What do you mean by "subtitle" -- a subscript, maybe? Please advise.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a subsection title like: \subsection{$\loghi$ mass}

Comment: More next to egreg's answer, I think you shouldn't. You shouldn't define (IMHO) commands to short the input, you should define *entities* (as in egreg's answer: `\Hi`, `\SFR`, `\Mo`), and then use a snippet 3rd party app (if your editor doesn't have snippets) to input fast, e.g., you can teach it to work if you use `li` + TAB and then print in your document `\log\Hi`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating macros that provide shortcuts for frequently used strings is a very good idea. For an entry-level introduction to the uses of the LaTeX `\newcommand` directive see, e.g., Chapter 6, "Customizing LaTeX", of the guide [The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX2e](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/).

For instance, you could issue the instructions

```
\newcommand\loghi{\log(\mathrm{H}\textsc{i})}
\newcommand\sfrm{\log(\mathrm{SFR} / \mathrm{M}_{\odot})}
```

in the preamble and, later on in the body of the text, write something like

```
bleet bleet $\loghi=\sfrm$ more bleet bleet
```

As you've already noted in a comment, a complication arises if these macros can also be used in **bold** surroundings such as sectioning headers. Specifically, given the above definition of `\loghi`, LaTeX will try to typeset the letter `i` in bold-smallcaps. As you've discovered, if the font family you're using does not feature a bold-smallcaps font, the letter will be set in "ordinary" bold, i.e., as **i**. Not the desired effect, right?!

What to do? I think you have (at least) two options. The first is to use a font family that does feature a bold-smallcap font. Two such families are`newt xtext`/`newtxmath` and `newpxtext`/`newpxmath` . The former provides a "Times Roman" look, the latter a "Palatino" look. This may (or may not...) be acceptable to you.

Second, you could set up the macro that defines `\loghi` in such a way that it won't even try to use a (possibly nonexistent) bold smallcaps glyph. For instance,

```
\newcommand\loghi{\log(\mathrm{H}\textsc{\mdseries i})}
```

(note the addition of `\mdseries` to the argument of `\textsc`) instructs LaTeX to apply `\textsc` to a "medium weight" (rather than a "bold weight") version of `i`. As long as the medium-weight font features smallcaps glyphs, you'll be guaranteed success.

Comment: Fantastic answer and details. I really appreciate the advice on this one. Thank you.

Comment: @Carl - Thanks for the compliment! Incidentally, if the symbols "H" and "i" belong together in some way, it may be better -- from a syntactic point of view -- to set up the shortcut macro as `\newcommand\loghi{\log(\textsc{\mdseries Hi})}`. An uppercase letter is rendered "as is" when subjected to `\textsc`, so the look of "H" using either definition will be the same. Nevertheless, even though the appearance will be the same, it's still useful to tailor the shortcut definition to obey all syntactic aspects of the expression at hand.

Comment: If you want to use the macro in header *and* use the `hyperref` package, you should also wrap it in  a `\texorpdfstring`

Comment: @Arian - I'm not sure how your comment relates the posting's topic, which is how to go about creating shortcuts for recurring expressions. Do verify for yourself that the issue with `hyperref` (specifically, the possible need for a `\texorpdfstring` directive) arises equally if the expression is generated via a shortcut macro or if it is written out fully from the start, i.e., without a shortcut macro.

Answer (score 7):

I would split the problem into two parts. First you define the elementary symbols, then expressions in terms of them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%% first the symbols
\newcommand{\Hi}{\textnormal{H\kern-.1em\textsc{i}}}
\newcommand{\SFR}{\mathrm{SFR}}
\newcommand{\Mo}{\mathrm{M}_{\odot}}
%% then common expressions
\newcommand{\lHi}{\log\Hi}
\newcommand{\lsfrmo}{\log(\SFR/\Mo)}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\log\Hi + \log(\SFR/\Mo)\\
\lHi+\lsfrmo
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

I've added some bit to the definition of `\Hi` just to show how you can redefine the elementary symbol without any need to modify also the definition of the expression defined in terms of it.

With `\textnormal{...}` we ensure the font will be the “initial” one, independently of the context. This is needed for `\Hi`, but not for `\SFR`; since `\mathrm` is more efficient than `\textnormal`, it's preferable when it's possible to use it.

[image]