# How to change how suspension points (dot dot dot) look with LaTeX?

Tags: punctuation, typography, ellipsis

### What I want to do

I know it is bad, but I would like to redefine how `\ldots` and its equivalents (the Unicode character `…` for instance) are rendered by TeX.

Indeed, in my opinion, with LaTeX, the suspension points don't look great... I know that this is the way it should looks, but I prefer how they generally look on electronic documents.

### Examples

[image]
[image]

### My questions

- Is this already done somewhere?
- So far, I have tried this, but the result is not satisfactory and I'm afraid that some typographic rules (the French ones for instance... actually, I intend to use the French rules) won't always be applied (imagine some dots in a bracket...). Can you help me to improve it?

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2026}{...}
  \renewcommand{\ldots}{...}

  \begin{document}
  With \LaTeX, the suspension points don't look great\ldots I know that this is the way it should looks, but I prefer how they generally look on electronic documents.
  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: Look at the `ellipsis` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`ellipsis` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/ellipsis) provides an easy means to adjust the gap between ellipsis dots. Specifically, `\setlength{\ellipsisgap}{<len>}` will adjust the space to `<len>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ellipsis}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \ldots{} consectetur adipiscing elit. 

\setlength{\ellipsisgap}{0.1em}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \ldots{} consectetur adipiscing elit. 

\setlength{\ellipsisgap}{0.05em}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \ldots{} consectetur adipiscing elit. 

\end{document}
```

---

A more direct method (less flexible than using `ellipsis`) would be to redefine `\ldots` from the kernel. In text mode, `\ldots` defaults to `\textellipsis` and is defined as (see [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textellipsis}{%
   .\kern\fontdimen3\font
   .\kern\fontdimen3\font
   .\kern\fontdimen3\font}
```

Here's an adjustment that uses a fixed .5pt gap between each `.`:

```
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textellipsis}{%
   .\kern.5pt
   .\kern.5pt
   .\kern\fontdimen3\font}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \ldots consectetur adipiscing elit. 

\renewcommand{\textellipsis}{%
   .\kern.5pt
   .\kern.5pt
   .\kern\fontdimen3\font}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \ldots consectetur adipiscing elit. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I prefer `ellipsis`. I can't believe that `\dots` does not work and that one should put `\dots{}`...

Comment: @Colas: TeX gobbles the space after a control sequence (like `\dots`). If you wish to avoid this, you can consider using the [`xspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) that peaks ahead to see if a space should be inserted. [`ellipses`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ellipsis) can be passed the package option `[xspace]` which would load the named package and allow you to use `\dots` without adding the empty group `\dots{}`. Your choice, but consider [Drawbacks of `xspace`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/5764).

Comment: @Werner `\ellipsisgap` is not a length and `\setlength{\ellipsisgap}{<dimen>}` works indirectly and changes globally the font parameter. See this comment http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179541/how-to-make-ellipsis-work-with-sans-serif-font?noredirect=1#comment415239_179566 to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179541/4686

Comment: @Werner See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179793/8323