# How to make ellipsis work with sans serif font?

Tags: fonts, typography, sans-serif, ellipsis

### Problem/question

It seems that the `ellipsis` package does not work with sans-serif fonts. Is it a known problem or maybe not a problem at all? This question follows [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179351/how-to-change-how-suspension-points-dot-dot-dot-look-with-latex), about "how to change the appearance of `\dots`"?

Thank you.

### MWE (minimal working example)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ellipsis}
\setlength{\ellipsisgap}{0.05em}

\begin{document}

{\sffamily So\dots{} let's see\dots{}}

So\dots{} let's see\dots{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### edit

Based on David's answer, here is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ellipsis}
\setlength{\ellipsisgap}{0.05em}
{\sffamily\setlength{\ellipsisgap}{0.05em}}
{\bfseries\setlength{\ellipsisgap}{0.05em}}

\begin{document}

{\normalfont So\dots{} let's see\dots{}}

{\sffamily So\dots{} let's see\dots{}}

{\bfseries So\dots{} let's see\dots{}}

So\dots{} let's see\dots{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is it that isn't working properly in the example you've provided?

Comment: @dbmag9 The spacing in `\sffamily`'s `\dots` is not what he wants (`0.05em`).

Comment: Isn't `em` relative to the type size?

Comment: @dbmag9 Yes, but if you change the value, the spacing doesn't change.

Comment: @dbmag9 em is relative to the type size _at the point the length is set_ the length register is a fixed length.

Comment: If it's only for text, why don't you directly type `…` (U+2026), (using UTF8 input encoding, of course)? If you're using a french layout keyboard, there are free drivers that allow you do that easily (and much more). You can take a look here: http://accentuez.mon.nom.free.fr/Clavier-Galeron.htm

Comment: @Colas your code appears to work by a sort of miracle, which is a bit technical. `\ellipsisgap` is not length, nevertheless your `\setlength` do not raise errors, quite the contrary they even work globally not obeying the scope limitations due to the braces!! but I do not recommend to do this because it permanently alters font parameters. Besides replace `0.05em` by `1cm` and you will see the side effects.

Comment: @jfbu Thanks for your help. Maybe you could add your point of view to this previous question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179351/how-to-change-how-suspension-points-dot-dot-dot-look-with-latex

Comment: @jfbu I want to make the dots closer one to each other. IMHO, by default, the space between them is too wide.

Comment: @Colas closer? then you need to use a negative value for the dimension used in  `\ellipsisgap`. `\renewcommand{\ellipsisgap}{\dimexpr-0.05em\relax}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\ellipsigap` is ***not*** a length register, but a macro! Doing

```
\setlength{\ellipsisgap}{0.5em}
```

or any other value is a big mistake. The definition of `\ellipsisgap` in the package is

```
\newcommand{\ellipsisgap}{\fontdimen3\font}
```

and `\setlength{\ellipsisgap}{0.5em}` will do, according to the definition of `\setlength`,

```
\ellipsisgap0.5em\relax
```

Now `\ellipsisgap` will be expanded and the assignment

```
\fontdimen3\font0.5em\relax
```

will be executed! This will change the parameter controlling the stretch component of interline glue. And the change is ***global***, affecting the current font.

The command `\ellipsisgap` should be changed with `\renewcommand`, as the documentation tells to (page 2, last code example in section 2).

By default, it gives the same space used as the stretch component in the interword spaces. You can change it to suit your needs, using `em` units. In the Computer Modern fonts, the stretch component is 0.6em; the same for roman and sans serif type.

---

Maybe the package should do

```
\renewcommand{\ellipsisgap}{\fontdimen3\font\relax}
```

so using `\setlength{\ellipsisgap}{...}` would at least throw an error.

Comment: Great answer ! Have you seen that @Werner?

Comment: @egreg had you seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179541/how-to-make-ellipsis-work-with-sans-serif-font/179767?noredirect=1#comment415239_179566?

Comment: @jfbu No, I had not seen them, sorry. I felt urgent to tell *why* `\setlength{\ellipsisgap}{...}` should not be used.

Comment: @egreg I felt the same urgency and hence posted immediately my three comments. In retrospect I should have added their contents to the body of my answer.

Comment: Even if I don't know TeX, I am sure you will agree with me to say that `\relax` is very important :-)

Comment: Why? Yours is clearer. You explain what is going on.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ellipsis}
\renewcommand{\ellipsisgap}{\dimexpr0.05em\relax}

\begin{document}

\textsf{So\dots{} let's see\dots{}}

So\dots{} let's see\dots{}


\LARGE

\textsf{So\dots{} let's see\dots{}}

So\dots{} let's see\dots{}

\end{document}
```

**Update:**

As I pointed out in my comments [A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179541/how-to-make-ellipsis-work-with-sans-serif-font/179767?noredirect=1#comment415239_179566)  (the corresponding answer by @DavidCarlisle has now been deleted) and 
[B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179351/how-to-change-how-suspension-points-dot-dot-dot-look-with-latex#comment415278_179353), and this [third comment to the present question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179541/how-to-make-ellipsis-work-with-sans-serif-font/179767?noredirect=1#comment415249_179541) all posted very shortly after this answer, the `\ellipsisgap` is not a skip register but a macro. `\setlength` works on it but does a font dimen assignment (automatically `global`).

The `\dimexpr` allows, now that `\ellipsisgap` is a size specification to do things like `\kern2\ellipsisgap` which omitting the `\dimexpr` would not permit. However, if there is no use for this, then `\renewcommand{\ellipsisgap}{0.05em}` would also work because, as it turns out, all its uses in `ellipsis.sty` are properly terminated.

> [image: ellipsis gap]

Comment: The `\dimexpr` is irrelevant and useless.

Comment: @egreg At the time of writing this answer I had not looked at `ellipsis.sty`, and did not know how `\ellipsisgap` was used within the package (in view of the other postings on this site, it appears I was not  alone). This being done I can confirm your `irrelevant and useless` caracterisation and extend it to the ending `\relax`.