# Insert a breaking (not no-breaking) space after text provided through macro

Tags: spacing

Is there a way to force lualatex to insert a single space that is not no-breaking?

---

**Why I ask:**

In my documents I have to refer to certain standards, program names or other oddities quite regularly. Rather than typing their names over and over again (which can be lengthy at times) I have tried to find an alternative solution. (Sadly I have not used the glossary package which would probably have been better at the time.)

My solution was to simply define new commands for each e.g. program name. For example:

```
\newcommand{\IDA}{IDA ICE 4.5}
```

The problem is that I will now have to enter a `~` after each use of `\IDA`. This is needed as `... \IDA is used ...` would be printed as `... IDA ICE 4.5is used ...` rather than the correct `... IDA ICE 4.5 is used ...`.

This works fine (lucky me) for all bot one instance where the attached word sticks out at the right edge of the paragraph.

Is there a way to force lualatex to insert a single space that is not no-breaking?

Comment: `\newcommand{\IDA}{IDA ICE 4.5~}`? (more elaborate things can be done with the xspace package).

Comment: you can just use a space `\newcommand{\IDA}{IDA ICE 4.5 }` if it is always followed by a space, or if not do not follow the macro by `~` but by `\ ` or `{} ` `\IDA{} `  will have a normal soace after it

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Adding the ~ into the macro as been my first idea. However is does not work if I need the `.` right after the text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Just adding the space to the \newcommand also did not work. Again due to the need of `,` or `.` following the \DIA at times. Using `{}` instead of `~` does however seem to be exactly what I needed! Thanks.

Comment: There is xspace package which adds space or not depending if punctuation follows, although I don't really recommend it (despite writing it:-)

Comment: See also [Drawbacks of `\xspace`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why don't you recommend it? What the catch?

Comment: Never mind. just read egreg's comment.