# soul for text highlighting, microtype for letterspacing, and xspace: incompatibility

Tags: macros, delimiters, soul, xspace

I am trying to use `soul` for highlighting text and `microtype` for letter spacing (and other things). But I cannot get the two to work together nicely when I include `xspace` (I use this mainly for abbreviations).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand\myabbrev[1]{\MakeTextLowercase{\textsc{\textls{#1}}}\xspace}

\def\XSPACE{\myabbrev{xspace}}
\def\HIGHLIGHT{\myabbrev{highlight}}
\soulregister{\XSPACE}{7}% breaks \xspace
\soulregister{\HIGHLIGHT}{0}% breaks \texthl

% \def\TEST/{\myabbrev{TEST}}
% \soulregister{\TEST}{7}% does not work

\begin{document}

\texthl{Now \XSPACE does not work}. \\ \bigskip

\texthl{Now \HIGHLIGHT does not work}.

\end{document}
```

If I use `\soulregister ... {7}` then `xspace` has no effect. If I use `\soulregister ... {0}` then `xspace` works, but the highlighting does not work.

[image]

Is it possible to fix this? If not, I would also be happy to use the "[delimited macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147061/11984)" approach (i.e. `\def\TEST/{\myabbrev{text}`) so that I do not forget the space. But this does not appear to work with `soulregister`, i.e `\soulregister{\TEST/}{7}` does not work.

Comment: I'm not at all surprised. ;-)

Comment: @egreg Well, knowing most of the discussions on `xspace` and `soul`, I hesitated to ask the question. But this has been nagging me for some time...

Comment: What's the reason for using `\xspace` in a command with an argument? The only one I can think to is “trying to shoot at one's own foot”.

Comment: @egreg Okay, I forget about using `\xspace`. Any idea regarding `\soulregister{\TEST/}{7}`?