# Using user defined commands in linguex without gobbling space

Tags: xspace, linguex

I use `linguex` together with own defined commands to get grammatical categories typeset in small-caps. For instance, I have `\newcommand{\sg}{\textsc{sg}}` to typeset the SG (=singular) gloss. This is also convenient if I want to change my glossing scheme. This creates however a slight inconvenience, since commands "gobble" the space after them. So in order to get the glosses correct I have to put {} after each such command, as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\newcommand{\sg}{\textsc{sg}}

\begin{document}

I would like this to work, but it doesn't:

\exg. I am here! \\
1\sg be.1\sg here \\


Instead, I have to use this syntax:

\exg. I am here! \\
1\sg{} be.1\sg{} here \\


\end{document}
```

Using `\xspace` in the command definition doesn't help. Is there some other solution which can help me avoid using {} all the time?

Comment: Please give us a full MWE in order to start with your problem. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't help with the `{}` issue, but you might be interested to know that there is a package [`leipzig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/leipzig) that provides a lot of macros for gloss abbreviations, plus has functionality to work with `glossaries` and produce a list of the gloss abbreviations used throughout the document and their full forms.

Comment: The problem is that `\exg` uses spaces for splitting the input into parts so as to be able to align them. But after `\sg` there is *no* space, because it is ignored at tokenization time and so it's not seen during the action of the macro expansion processor. David's trick requires special formatting, adding `{}` doesn't. Would you be satisfied if instead of `\sg{}` you had to type `\sg*`? Otherwise, I can offer a syntax where the different items are separated, say, by `//`

Comment: @egreg, using * would not be good, since I already use the starred versions to get some other result (a full text). The basic problem is that sometimes I forget the `{}` and then I get misaligned examples. So changing the separator will probably not solve my problem.

Comment: @egreg, thinking more about it, a reasonable alternative would be if I could use a dot `.` after the command, which shouldn't be printed if it is followed by space, but otherwise it should appear. So `\sg.\masc.' could give *SG.MASC*

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I'd recommend it but you could locally make a space not a normal space, so that it is not dropped after `\foo` then replace all the special spaces by normal spaces so the `\exg` macro sees them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\newcommand{\sg}{\textsc{sg}}

\def\zztmp{\$}
{\obeyspaces\catcode`\~10\relax\makeatletter
\gdef\zz{\begingroup\obeyspaces\zzz}%
\gdef\zzz#1{\endgroup\zzzz{}#1 \$ }%
\gdef\zzzz#1#2 {%
\def\tmp{#2}\ifx\tmp\zztmp
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\fi
{#1}{\zzzz{#1#2~}}}}

\begin{document}

I would like this to work, but it doesn't:

\zz{
\exg. I am here! \\
1\sg be.1\sg here \\
}


Instead, I have to use this syntax:

\exg. I am here! \\
1\sg{} be.1\sg{} here \\


\end{document}
```

Comment: I've no clue how your code works, but it does seem to do the trick!

Comment: Trying this in my real document, however, it does not seem to work. In the real document I embed the `\exg.` within other commands, and so I tried to embed the `\zz` together with it, but for some reason it doesn't produce the same result. I load many different packages, so maybe one of them affects this...

Comment: @Ariel any command based on catcode changes is like `\verb` and can't be used in the argument of another command. You can almost certainly lift the space handling up to your top level document command, but to be honest I wouldn't it is a massively intrusive change for essentially at best cosmetic results, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620 for similar concerns. Just accept the answer as best that's possible but use `{}` in the document:-)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `\exg` uses spaces for splitting the input into parts so as to be able to align them. But after `\sg` there is no space, because it is ignored at tokenization time and so it's not seen during the action of the macro expansion processor. So a solution might be to follow these special commands with a period.

As requested, the period prints only if the next token is not a space. The disadvantage is that the period is *mandatory* after the abbreviations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newabbreviation}[2]{%
  \@ifdefinable{#1}{\@newabbreviation{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand\@newabbreviation[2]{%
  \def#1.{#2\@checkspace}%
}
\newcommand\@checkspace{%
  \futurelet\@let@token\@check@space
}
\newcommand\@check@space{%
  \ifx\@let@token\@sptoken\else.\fi
}
\makeatother

\newabbreviation{\sg}{\textsc{sg}}
\newabbreviation{\masc}{\textsc{masc}}

\begin{document}

This seems to work:

\exg. I am here! \\
1\sg. be.1\sg.\masc. here \\

\end{document}
```

I apologize for the linguistic blasphemy in the example. `;-)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I see this is really a complicated problem which has to do with the very inner workings of TeX.... Is it not possible to make the . optional? Otherwise, I would have to rewrite all my previous examples.

Comment: @Ariel No, sorry; in my opinion it's an error of `linguex` using the space as the chunk delimiter to begin with. As ignoring spaces after control sequences is a rule of TeX, there's little you can do except trying the “envelope” method suggested by David.