# Detect when a white space is needed after calling a command

Tags: xparse, tex-general

Say I have an expression I often use so I build a command shortcut to typeset it:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ProvideDocumentCommand \es{s}{expression shortcut\IfBooleanTF{#1}{s}{}}
\begin{document}
This is a \es and These are \es*.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can I avoid the manual addition of tilde (~) when the call is made within a sentence? In other words, is there a way to detect (using `xparse` or not) when Latex shouldn't "eat" the following white space?

Comment: Do you know about `\xspace` from the eponymous package?

Comment: tex will always eat the space in deciding which command it is, however as Paul says you can use xspace to put the space back, but before doing that read [drawbacks of xspace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620)

Comment: Well, since this is exactly what I need and since there appears to be no better way to do it, I'll use `xspace`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, according to The Not so short introduction to Latex (section 1.3.3), Latex ignores whitespaces after commands, so, quoting:

> If you want to get a space after a command, you have to put either an
>   empty parameter {} and a blank or a special spacing command after the
>   command name

So either you use empty arguments or something like `\hspace{0.5em}` (or whatever space suits you better).

**Edit**:

Following Paul's advice, I tried the \xspace command and the trick is to include \usepackage{xspace} and inside the definition, include the command, like

```
\ProvideDocumentCommand \es{s}{expression shortcut\IfBooleanTF{#1}{s}{}\xspace}
```

I just tested it :)

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the size of the space, it's better to use control space `\ ` so that TeX's glue is not adversely affected. And as mentioned in my comment above, there is also the option of `\xspace`. BTW, even though you've been around for a while, this is your first answer, so: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) :-)

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't know the option of \xspace, I think I will have to learn about it