# Spacing after alias

Tags: spacing, macros

I'm not sure whether I am repeating an already existent question or not, but I'd like to know how to approach the following situation:

I want to define a macro to be an alias to some word or fragment of text. When I define it, the space coming after the command is ignored and consequently the spacing between that word and the next one is deleted, as can be viewed in the MWE below.

The following code

```
\documentclass{report} 

\newcommand{\alias}{Paulo}
\newcommand{\altalias}{Paulo }
\newcommand{\formatalias}{%
    {\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\textsc{Paulo}}%
}
\newcommand{\altformatalias}{%
    {\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\textsc{Paulo}} %
}

\begin{document}

This is \alias, who is just checking \LaTeX's behaviour.\par
This is \alias who is just checking \LaTeX's behaviour.\par
This is \altalias who is just checking \LaTeX's behaviour.\par
This is \formatalias who is just checking \LaTeX's behaviour.\par
This is \altformatalias who is just checking \LaTeX's behaviour.

\end{document}
```

outputs like this:

[image]

So my question is, am I doing it right by just adding a space at the end of my macro, or should I do something else?

Comment: No, you will have trouble at `\formatalias.` It will be `PAULO .` i.e., space before period. Use `\formatalias{}` instead.

Comment: As Harish says, or `\formatalias.` (swap `.` with whatever punctuation is appropriate) when punctuation immediately follows the macro and `\formatalias\ ` when a space should follow the macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you should do something else. Here are the options:

1. Use `\mymacro{}` even if the macro doesn't take an argument. The empty group `{}` at the end of `\mymacro` doesn't influence the output (in terms of spacing), but sets a space if a space follows the macro, or punctuation if that's the case. Sure, this may seem cumbersome, but you'll get used to it.
2. Use `\mymacro\`  to force a (control) space whenever you need it.
3. Use [`xspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace), [with caution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/5764)...

Comment: egreg will throw thunderbolts after you for `xspace` ;-)

Comment: You could consider adding a third option (still preferable to `xspace` IMHO): see [my comment on the question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235747/spacing-after-alias#comment558671_235747) for details.

Comment: Please, don't answer clear duplicates