# Trying to get the spacing right after an expanded sequence

Tags: spacing, xspace

I've defined

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\bar}{\foo{Bar}}
```

Now, when I compile

```
\bar tender --- tend your \bar.
```

I would like to get

> **Bar** tender - tend your **Bar**.

but what I actually get is

> **Bar**tender - tend your **Bar**.

It seems that if I use `\foo{Bar}` directly, I get what I want.

How can I get the output I expect by changing the command rather than the invocation? I'd rather not use `\xspace` unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: `\bar{} tender -- tend your \bar.`

Comment: @egreg: I'd sort of like the command itself to take care of that and for me not to need the empty group...

Comment: @einpoklum All (la)TeX command are like this so why this will be different?

Comment: @touhami: You could say I want the effect of textual replacement in this case rather than command expansion.

Comment: Then use xspace. Or check the code of xspace and do something similar in your command. Commands with names consisting of letters do swallow spaces.

Comment: @einpoklum Command expansion is exactly the same as textual replacement.

Comment: The space is not there, it is absorbed while recognising the command name, so if you want to put a space back you need to _add_ a space, either always or using xspace or whatever.

Comment: @einpoklum see egreg comment http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace

Comment: You can also do something like `\def\bar!{\textbf{foo}}\bar! blabla`.