# How declare numeric constants with space without ~

Tags: spacing, punctuation, kerning

I have written a document with some data that I must update at last minute. So I have created some `newcommand`:

```
%--------------------------------
% Insert data here
\newcommand{\srskm}{12,253~}
\newcommand{\srspercent}{1.53\%~}
\newcommand{\srssamples}{2,777,059~}
\newcommand{\srssamplesml}{2.8~}
\newcommand{\srsacc}{833~}
```

It is all right, but if I omit the tilde, the number will be insert without spacing.

**Question: There is a way to declare this data and obtain a spacing when after there is a word, and no spacing when after there is a punctuation?**

Comment: add `\xspace` where you have `~` from the eponymous package.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I obtain `Undefined control sequence. Example sentence: \srssamples` when I call `\newcommand{\srssamples}{2777059\xspace}` and the others.

Comment: You need the `xspace` package for `\xspace`

Comment: but see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't really answer your question, but will maybe solve your problem.

Use `{}` after calling the macros. You could/should also use `siunitx` for handling units or numerics. Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\srskm}{\num{12253}}
\newcommand{\srspercent}{\SI{1.53}{\percent}}
\newcommand{\srssamples}{\num{2777059}}
\newcommand{\srssamplesml}{\num{2.8}}
\newcommand{\srsacc}{\num{833}}

\begin{document}
  Example sentence: \srskm{} without and with punctuation \srskm{}. Works with \srspercent{} as well \srspercent{}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have read the documentation of `siunitx`: very interesting. Thank you.
You have solved partially my problem (I would like do not use the curly braces).

Comment: +1 I like your solution, e.g. `\newcommand{\srskm}{\SI{12253}{\km}}`. I extract the data from (http://smartroadsense.it/open-data.html)[SmartRoadSense] web site, where I have only two data (the first is the second per 300). And `\srspercent` is `\srskm/800000*100`. I try to define two variable and obtain the other data.