# xspace inserts a space when used inside \enquote

Tags: csquotes, xspace

Am I wrong in thinking that `\xspace` should *not* introduce a space when used inside an `\enquote` command as used in the following MWE? And how can I get the two to work together?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\test}{test\xspace}

\begin{document}
    \test. \test, ``\test'' \test \enquote{\test} \test \enquote{\test}. 
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from the MWE]

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620

Answer (score 8):

[image]

You can add `csquotes` end of argument marker to the `xspace` list of exceptions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xspace}
\makeatletter
\xspaceaddexceptions{\csq@qclose@i}
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\test}{test\xspace}

\begin{document}
    \test. \test, ``\test'' \test \enquote{\test} \test \enquote{\test}. 
\end{document}
```

But note problems like this are inevitable and predicted:

[Drawbacks of xspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620)