# Correctly handling spaces that occur after a user defined command

Tags: spacing, macros, luatex

I am using LuaLaTeX for a manual and I am running into a spacing issue I am not sure how to resolve. I defined a new command that is simply used to make some text bold. However, I have found that this command eats spaces that follow the command so that the bold word is right next to the word that follows. I don't want to add a space in the definition because sometimes the word comes at the end of a sentence and I don't want an extra space. Below is a sample. How do I get the `\lualatex` command to behave such that the command does not eat spaces that come after it?

```
\newcommand{\lualatex}{{\bf lualatex}}

This manual is written in \LaTeX and is processed via the 
\lualatex executable. The \lualatex executable has the Lua
scripting language embedded which provides a power method
of extending the capability of \lualatex.
```

Comment: The standard \LaTeX-command eats space too. What did you do to avoid it?

Comment: I guess it does. I hadn't looked closely enough at this.

Comment: So is there a way to handle this for the \LaTeX comand as well?

Comment: You can use the xspace package to automatically insert a space . But in the long run it is better to get use to end such commands with `{}` or ` \ ` when using them. See also this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/2388

Comment: Off-topic here but two things: `\bf` has been deprecated in LaTeX2e for over _twenty years_ (use `\textbf{lualatex}` here); the 'common' style for executables is monospaced (`\texttt{lualatex}`) (your call, of course).

Comment: Ok. I wasn't aware this was depricated. Thanks for the info. And the previous responses did address this quiestion. Thanks for the help.