# Extra space in renewcommand

Tags: macros

I use this code to add an extra space in the `frqq` command:

```
\let\oldfrqq\frqq
\renewcommand{\frqq}{\oldfrqq\xspace}
```

It compiles, but generates an error when it is used:

```
! Undefined control sequence
\frqq ->\oldfrqq \xspace
```

Is `oldfrqq`  undefined? How should I make it work?

Comment: Is `\frqq` defined at all? If I use `\providecommand{\frqq}{foo}` there's no error.

Comment: Sure. \frq, \flq, \frqq, \flqq are the Swiss guillemots and they are displayed.

Comment: Which package do you use? I've never seen those commands so far!

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem.

Comment: The answer of D. Carlisle is correct, it works now, thank you.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I believe those guillemots are available because of the babel package: `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` option that I use, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Gerard: I am German and use `babel` that way, but I've never used such Swiss guillemots. It would have been nice to see the code you have, I could have tracked the error as well, but I've included `\usepackage{xspace}` already and searched the error at the wrong place.  Please post full examples not just fragments! (By the way: I am not the downvoter ;-))

Comment: you can also make your code more readable using `\usepackage{etoolbox}` ... `\apptocmd{\frqq}{\xspace}{}{}`

Comment: Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In my case simply `\space` works as well.

Comment: @Werner To be honest the MWE requirement often feels like just too much effort in relation to the problem ..?

Comment: @Gerard: This is a poor question, as there is no context given. Specifically, the formatting of the error message is ambiguous: The error could have been with an non-existent `\oldfrqq` *or* `\xspace`. Also, the question title doesn't have anything to do with the question once you know the answer. Finally, this has nothing to do with [tag:macros], but more with the vague [tag:errors] tag.

Comment: Also note that *you* are asking for help here... when the community requests something that would clarify the problem, spoon-feeding is definitely a good idea. Answers here seem free-of-charge, but it has to be well-formulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that `\xspace` is undefined, presumably because you have not loaded the package of that name