# How to add suffixes to `\newcommand`s in TEX?

Tags: macros

I have defined a term using a new command as follows:

> \newcommand{\ourmethod}{G-MM\xspace}

Now I'd like to add a suffix to the term that I just defined, e.g. I'd like to use "\ourmethod" to say G-MMs (note that there is an "s" added to the term). How can I do this in LATEX?

Comment: Under what conditions do you want `\ourmethod` to print `G-MM` or `G-MMs`? You can, of course, do `\renewcommand{\ourmethod}{G-MMs}`.

Comment: It would be easier if you [had not used `xspace`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/1090). As it is, `\ourmethod{}s` wil do the right thing most of the time, but having `\xspace{}` before the `s` will break any font specified kerns between the last two letters, and affect possible hyphenation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: @Werner: I would like to be able to add arbitrary suffixed to the command without having to define a new command for every new suffix. So, I'd like to keep `\ourmethod` to translate to `G-MM`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should follow David's recommendation. But, if you still want to use `xspace` (or even if you decide not to), I would suggest you define both the singular and plural once with something like:

```
\DefineTerms{ourmethod}{G-MM}
```

which creates the two macros: `\ourmethod` and `\ourmethods`:

[image]

---

Alternativly, you could define the command where you provide the suffix as an optional parameter in square brackets:

```
\newcommand{\ourmethod}[1][]{G-MM#1\xspace}
```

[image]

---

### Code: Using `etoolbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\DefineTerms}[2]{%
    \csdef{#1}{#2\xspace}%
    \csdef{#1s}{#2s\xspace}%
}

\DefineTerms{ourmethod}{G-MM}

\begin{document}
\verb|\ourmethod|: \ourmethod

\verb|\ourmethods|: \ourmethods
\end{document}
```

### Code: Without `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\DefineTerms}[2]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{#2\xspace}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1s\endcsname{#2s\xspace}%
}

%\newcommand{\ourmethod}{G-MM\xspace}
\DefineTerms{ourmethod}{G-MM}

\begin{document}
\verb|\ourmethod|: \ourmethod

\verb|\ourmethods|: \ourmethods
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: Optional Parameter

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\ourmethod}[1][]{G-MM#1\xspace}

\begin{document}
\verb|\ourmethod|: \ourmethod

\verb|\ourmethod[s]|: \ourmethod[s]
\end{document}
```