# Typesetting abbreviations with a slash?

Tags: typography, acronyms

In letters written in the early 20th century, for the German word “bei”, the
author commonly uses the abbreviation “ᵇ/”. Currently I typeset as follows:

```
26.4.17 \textsuperscript{b}/La Selve
```

The result, however, is an unpleasant space between the superscript “b” and the
slash. Of course I could manually adjust space, but I wonder:

*Is there a recommended way of typesetting abbreviations like that? Any
 dedicated package?*

Comment: How about creating a command that takes the abbreviation letter as an argument, then puts it in superscript and adds negative kerning and a slash?

Comment: Or something a bit more complex using a box to resize and place the letter exactly where you want it, because even though I have not tested the result, I feel like you may want a bigger font size than regular superscript and maybe better vertical positioning too.

Comment: As for packages, I think the best you can find is a package that wraps all of your commands into a list of abbreviations, but it will not provide for the typography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never seen such an abbreviation, but it's easy to obtain it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\bei}{\textsuperscript{b}\kern-.3em}

\begin{document}

Abcdef \bei/La Selve

\end{document}
```

You could also add the `/` in the definition of `\bei`, if you prefer, but it has the disadvantage that a space after `\bei` would need `{}`.

Alternatively, in order to be sure you do have a slash after `\bei` is

```
\newcommand{\bei}{}% just for safety
\def\bei/{\textsuperscript{b}\kern-.3em/}
```

and the usage is as before.

[image]

Comment: are you quite sure there shouldn't be a space between the slash and the word that follows?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I took the input from the OP

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with this specific abbreviation. For what I understand from your question, I'd suggest the microtype package (needs LuaLaTex).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand*{\mybei}{\textls[-190]{\emph{\textsuperscript{b}}/}\xspace}
\newcommand*{\mybeis}{\textls[-300]{\textsuperscript{b}/}\xspace}
\newcommand*{\mybeit}{\textls[-190]{\textsuperscript{b}/}\xspace}

\begin{document}
    There is a \mybei here. Can I use the abbreviation \mybeit to say \mybeis uns in Deutschland?
\end{document}
```

The kerning between "b" and "/" can be adapted by \textls.

Comment: You must not use `\xspace`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/50058