# Can I inject \xspace in all commands from the complexity package?

Tags: macros, xspace

The `complexity` package is a very useful one for a Computer Scientist. Recently, I've discovered the `xspace` package, which provides the `\xspace` macro that helps defining macros that do not need the `\` escape to avoid globbing a subsequent whitespace:

```
\newcommand{\myname}{Nicola\xspace}
...
\myname is walking on the street % No need to write \myname\ or \myname{}
```

Now, I use a *lot* of commands from the complexity package, which defines tens of commands that are commonly used inside text so that the need of escaping is very frequent. I would like to have them use `\xspace` by default, but redefining, say, `\ComplexityFont` does not work, because apparently `\xspace` must be put exactly at the end of the macro being invoked (not a macro expanded from it). The package defines all its macros with simple `\newcommand`s, so I don't think there is a way to hook into it.

Is this redefinition possible to automate in some way, or should I suggest this feature to the package author directly?

Comment: From the manual: “Thus, it’s best to always use complexity commands inside math mode.”

Comment: Didn't think about that. But if I have to write $\NP$ I could as well write \NP{}. Does `\xspace` cause problems in math mode? If not, it could still be a nice thing to do.

Comment: It's never a good idea to use `\xspace`. ;-)

Comment: And, looking at the package, you also must train into using `$\protect\NP$` whenever `\NP` appears in a section title.

Comment: Can you expand (no pun intended :P ) your opinion about `\xspace`, please? :)

Comment: See [Drawbacks of `\xspace`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since essentially all commands are defined in terms of `\ComplexityFont`, it is quite easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[small]{complexity}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xspace}

\robustify\ComplexityFont
\apptocmd\ComplexityFont{\xspace}{}{}


\begin{document}

\section{An \NP problem}

An \NP problem

\end{document}
```

I also robustified the main command, so you don't need `\protect` in front of the `complexity` macros when in moving arguments, such as those of `\section` and `\caption`.

However, my advice is to follow what the author says in the manual:

> Thus, it’s best to always use `complexity` commands inside math mode.

Read [Drawbacks of xspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace) for reasons why not using `\xspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[small]{complexity}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\robustify\ComplexityFont    

\begin{document}

\section{An $\NP$ problem}

An $\NP$ problem

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for having solved the problem in the question even if in disagree with the goal :)

Comment: Btw, the same is needed for `\lang` and `\func`, because `\ComplexityFont` is only used for class names.

Comment: @gigabytes That's highly possible.

Comment: @gigabytes he always likes a chance to use my packages.