# How to get "MATLAB" symbol in Latex?

Tags: symbols, matlab

Looking for something similar to \LaTeX. It is correct in this section from my textbook. [image: The way my textbook has it is what I'm looking for:]

Comment: Use `\textsc{Matlab}` to get the above output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you say you're looking for a command similar to `\LaTeX`, you can define something like

```
\newcommand{\MATLAB}{\textsc{Matlab}\xspace}
```

Here, I have used the [xspace](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace) package to prevent the `\MATLAB` command from "eating" spaces after it. Maybe there is a cleaner solution, but this definitely works fine. Just add also

```
\usepackage{xspace}
```

to the preamble.

Comment: ...and also read [Drawbacks of `xspace`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/5764).

Comment: That is a good point! I did not notice any problems using the xspace package, however, if you do, or just want to play it safe, just omit `\xspace` in the command definition and use `\MATLAB{}` every time.