# Can I make a macro not collapse subsequent spaces?

Tags: spacing

Here's my command for formatting a particular word.

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\textsf{FOO}}
```

Used like this

```
This is \foo and \foo.
```

it produces the following

[image]

In plain text, the output is `FOOand FOO.`, with no space after either `FOO`.

I want my command to behave spatially as if I had typed `FOO` instead of `\foo`. That is, the space which follows `\foo` should not be collapsed, so there would be whitespace before the `and` but not before the full stop.

How can I do this?

Comment: look into the `xspace` package

Comment: Also see [Drawbacks of `xspace`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/5764).