# Shortcut for command without braces

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I want to create a shortcut for

`\textsubscriptARGS`

With `ARGS` being any number.

I want to type something like `123\a33332` and have the same output as `123\textsubscript{33332}`

I tried with `\def` and `\newcommand` unsuccessfully 
Thanks!

I tryed \def\aa #1#2#3{\textsubscript{#1#2#3}} and it works but only if there are 3 args, do you know how to set the args as optional or to include all the characters before a space as one arg?

Comment: Should it handle decimals as well, or only whole numbers? What about negative numbers? What is the delimiter that identifies the end of this number... a space? What if you have a sentence-ending `123\a33332.`?

Comment: Welcome to the site =) There are some wizards here who might come along and blow me away, but I'm really not optimistic, braces are what LaTeX uses to delimit arguments. Making `123\a{33332}` work is easy as pie (although it might be better to pick a different name to `\a`) But what you are trying to do flies so roundly in the face of how LaTeX works that there *are* better things to do with your time, like finding an editor that can help you with subscripts

Comment: @Werner and how will LaTeX tell argument from command `\a3` will be read as one command won't it?

Comment: @Au101: Numbers are not allowed in control sequences (by default, unless defined using `\csname`...`\endcsname`).

Comment: i just tryed found an example in the internet and i edited it to work, thanks for the interest: \def\aa #1#2#3{\textsubscript{#1#2#3}}

Comment: @Werner Oh! Well there you go, learn something new every day don't you; i'm really glad you asked the question now rusty =)

Comment: @rusty can you edit that into the question? The example you were experimenting with?

Comment: @rusty: That will only work if you *always* have 3 numbers. That is, `\aa123` would be fine, but `\aa1234` would not work as expected. The same goes for `\aa12`.

Comment: yes i just noticed it and i updated the question, using \def with args doesnt seems ideal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has all kinds of wrong written over it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\def\aa#1 {\textsubscript{#1}\xspace}

\begin{document}

Here is some 123\aa4 text together with
        some 123\aa45 text together with
        some 123\aa456 text together with
        some 123\aa4567 text together with
        some 123\aa45678 text together with
        some 123\aa456789 text together with
        some 123\textsubscript{4567890}.

\end{document}
```

Why?

- `\aa` is already defined (as the Swedish letter å).
- There is no consistency in usage for `\aa` at the end of a sentence, since `\def`'s parameter text *requires* a space as the ending delimiter for its argument. Conditioning on a `.` would be okay, but what happens with `,`, or `!`, or `?`, or ...
- See [Drawbacks of `xspace`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/5764).

Comment: In the words of Doctor Who "Many things about this are not good" :P Good job though, I'm actually surprised it was that easy! =)

Comment: As a Scandinavian I take offence to calling `\aa` the ångström symbol ;-)

Comment: @daleif. If you want the actual *letter* Å, you should probably type that directly, while using `\aa` for the symbol. Similar to how TeX does not support `\Alpha`, because it doesn't make sense to use that as a *symbol*, and if you want it as a letter, you should just type the actual letter. (Disclaimer: I have no idea what I'm talking about. I read this site a lot, but don't actually use TeX myself.)

Comment: @TRiG `\aa` is not Å (that is `\AA`), `\aa` is å, and both is a vowel used in Scandinavia.

Comment: @daleif: I hope my correction is okay. My Swedish (or Scandinavian) is non-existent.

Comment: Better, though I'm Danish, see the wiki page for origin: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Å, the Ångström guy was probably Swedish.

Comment: In western Danish dialect you can do entire meaningful sentences entirely in vowels.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want integers, you *might* do as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\wrongwaytodosubscripts}{%
  \afterassignment\wwtdss\count255=
}
\def\wwtdss{\textsubscript{\the\count255}\xspace}

\begin{document}

123\wrongwaytodosubscripts123 followed by whatever.

123\wrongwaytodosubscripts123.

\end{document}
```

Whether I recommend doing it should be clear from the macro name I chose.

[image]

***Don't do like this!*** It's error prone and has several limitations.