# Command with a space after it

Tags: macros

Is it possible to define a command `\MyCommand` which does not swallow the next space (standard) but inserts a real space after itself only if the next symbol followed by it is a real space-symbol or CR? The command is supposed to have no arguments.

Comment: What's wrong with `\MyCommand{}`?

Comment: You can try xspace, but I wouldn't do it, but use {} after the command. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620

Answer (score 1):

No, because the following space has been swallowed by TeX's parser already before the command itself runs.

Comment: Do I right guess that an attempt to catch a space symbol after a command by construction`\@ifnextchar ... \fi` will not help?

Comment: @maximav The guess should not be about space symbols but about space tokens. (La)TeX' reading- and tokenizing-apparatus will not tokenize a space-character trailing something that was tokenized as a control word token. Besides this,the LaTeX2e-kernel-variant of `\@ifnextchar` cannot easily be used for checking for space-tokens. Internally it uses `\let` in a way where space-tokens will be treated as `<one optional space>` which will be discarded, leading to unpredictable results. This is rectified with some packages that redefine `\@ifnextchar`.