# How to present my code output in LaTeX?

Tags: code, pseudocode

I try to create an application that takes several inputs and represent them in a comprehensive manner. Let's say I have the following script:

```
x = 5
y = 'meters'
z = 'second'
```

and I want to get a pdf/output like this

> The speed is 5 meters/second

Is there any way to do it? Thank you in advance

Comment: yes this is a verycommon thing to do instead of equality you use `\def\myx{5}` etc. If you want to have units exclusively better use `siunitx` package.

Comment: As it is right now, the question is very unclear. Please clarify the input, and the conversion to output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\def\x/{5}
\def\y/{meters}
\def\z/{second}
The speed is \x/ \y//\z/

\def\x/{6}
\def\y/{kilometers}
\def\z/{hour}
The speed is \x/ \y//\z/

\end{document}
```

I used `/` to enable spaces after the macros, taking advice from [this answer - 'Drawbacks of xspace'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147061/128068).

Comment: I would clearly add, that this is not a very LaTeXy solution.