# An ellipsis with N dots

Tags: macros, luatex

How might one define a lualatex macro `\lip`, taking optional
arguments * and [N], such that, with no argument, the expansion is an
ellipsis consisting of three dots, with [N] it has N dots, and with *
its ends a sentence?
It should be possible to use it like \lip this, ie. without closing it
with `{}`.

PS.  Ideally, if the ellipsis is followed by a comma, the space between
the last dot and the comma should be the same as the space between the
dots.

Comment: What do you mean by “end a sentence”?

Comment: @egreg, spacefactor 3000.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need LuaLaTeX for this, it can be done quite easily with `expl3`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\lip{s O{3}}{
  $
    \prg_replicate:nn{#2}{\ldotp}
  $
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\spacefactor\sfcode`\.\relax}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Hello \lip, I know how to write dots: \lip*[10] Anyway \lip[3] not all dots end sentences.
\end{document}
```

Of course, if you use it like `some \lips words`, TeX will gobble the space. This is very hard to avoid even with LuaTeX because LuaTeX does not change the TeX parsing rules. Of course this problem does not exists if you use a star or the optional argument.

If you really need it, there are three options I can think of:

- Always add the space if no argument has been given. This would break e.g. at `\lip,` in the example above.
- Use `xspace` but remember the [drawbacks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,xspace}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\lip{s o}{
  $
    \prg_replicate:nn{\IfValueTF{#2}{#2}{3}}{\ldotp}
  $
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
    \spacefactor\sfcode`\.\relax
  }{
    \IfValueF{#2}{\xspace}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Hello \lip, I know how to write dots: \lip*[10] Anyway \lip not all dots end sentences.
\end{document}
```

- The "LuaTeX solution": Use a `process_input_buffer` callback to detect all input lines where `\lip` is used and always add an explicit space afterwards. This would be extremely fragile and will not interact properly with macros etc.

So it is much more reliable to just manually add `\` or `[3]` when this occurs.

Comment: You don't need expl3's `\prg_replicate:nn` or similar in your code, because it is anyhow not purely expandable, so simply using TeX/LaTeX `\loop` construct with a count can do the job.

Comment: @jfbu That would work, but I think `\prg_replicate:nn` looks much cleaner.

Comment: well, if document uses already expl3, you are certainly right

Comment: @jfbu Just loading `expl3` adds about 0.5 seconds of startup time to my LaTeX run.  I try to avoid loading it where possible.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\lip{\@ifstar{\let\@liptmp\relax\@lip}{\let\@liptmp\@\@lip}}
\newcommand\@lip[1][3]{{\uccode`m=`.\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1000}}\@liptmp\space \ignorespaces}

\begin{document}


aaa\lip[5] bbb aaa\lip bbb aaa\lip[7] bbb

aaa\lip*[5] bbb aaa\lip* bbb aaa\lip*[7] bbb

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 even without `\zz`!

Answer (score 1):

I guess that after `\lips*` you want a normal space (subject to the space factor):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

% the definition of \textellipsis is
% .\kern\fontdimen3\font
% repeated three times

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\lips}{sO{3}}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { .\kern\fontdimen3\font }
  \IfBooleanT{#1}
    { \unkern\spacefactor 3000 \scan_stop: \c_space_tl }
  \ignorespaces
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Three \lips Four \lips[4] Five \lips[5], with a comma

Here is \lips It was not end of sentence.

Here is \lips* It was end of sentence.

Here is \mbox{\lips\unkern} It was not end of sentence

\end{document}
```

The last line emulates a normal space not subject to the space factor, so to appreciate the difference.

[image]

Comment: looks as if the space before the ellipsis is larger than after.

Comment: @Toothrot It's a normal space. You didn't specify what you want.

Comment: oh i see what is going on.  the space after the ellipsis is unstrechable

Comment: @Toothrot I tried to guess, maybe you can be more precise.