# Create a command from parameter value

Tags: macros

I'm using `sides` to write a play.
To add a character you do:

```
\begin{castpage}
\cast{Bob SquarePants}{A sponge}
\end{castpage}
```

and then you do

```
\repl{Bob SquarePants} Plop!

\stage{\chara{Bob} do a flip.}
```

`\chara` being a shortcut to small cap a string

What I would like to do is override `\cast` to do what it does and declare a new command/alias using a value passed in parameter. Like so: `\cast{Bob SquarePants}{A sponge}{bob}` and the new command created `\bob` with the code being something like `\bob{\chara Bob}`.

The goal being to replace `\stage{\chara{Bob} do a flip.}` by `\stage{\bob do a flip.}`

I tried to do :

```
\let\oldCast\cast
\renewcommand{\cast}[3]{
    \oldCast{#1}{#2}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #3\endcsname{\chara ##1}
}
```

But I get the error `Illegal parameter number in definition of \bob` when I write `\cast{Bob SquarePants}{A sponge}{bob}`

EDIT:

Here is a MWE (commented what I'd like to achieve):

```
\documentclass{sides}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\def \stage{\stagedir}

\title{MWE}
\author{Foo}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newcommand*{\newcast}[3]{%
  \cast{#1}{#2}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #3\endcsname{\chara{#1}}%
}

\begin{castpage}
\newcast{Bob SquarePants}{A sponge}{bob}
\newcast{Patrick Star}{A starfish}{pat}
\end{castpage}

\newact
\newscene

\stage{Opens on a black stage.}
\repl{Bob SquarePants} I will do a flip!
\stage{\chara{Bob} do a flip.}%\stage{\bob do a flip}
\repl{Patrick Star} Amazing!
\stage{\chara{Bob} smiles and \chara{Patrick} applauds.} %\stage{\bob smiles and \pat applauds.}

\end{document}
```

The point of the command being to save some typing and not adding the same code for each new character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. Problems in your macro:

1. You are adding unwanted spaces. Please refer to [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/73317)
2. If you write `\cast{Bob SquarePants}{A sponge}{bob}`, when `\cast` is expanded, the whole will be replaced with:

   ```latex
   \oldCast{Bob SquarePants}{A sponge}
   \expandafter\newcommand\csname bob\endcsname{\chara #1}
   ```

   You see, the parameter tokens have been replaced by their values, and the `##` has been replaced by a single `#`. The problem is that after `\expandafter` is expanded, the last line will become:

   ```latex
   \newcommand\bob{\chara #1}
   ```

   In other words, it defines a macro that takes no argument but contains `#1` in its replacement text. This explains the error you obtained: “Illegal parameter number in definition of `\bob`.” `\bob` takes 0 arguments, but it is trying to use its first argument, hence an illegal parameter number.
3. Your definition of the character-specific new command is done using `\newcommand`, therefore it is local and will be forgotten after `\end{castpage}` if you use `\cast` inside `\begin{castpage} ... \end{castpage}` (environments define a TeX group).

What you need to fix point 2 is to use a single `#` and add braces around the `#1`, so that after one expansion step of `\cast{Bob SquarePants}{A sponge}{bob}`, one obtains:

```latex
\oldCast{Bob SquarePants}{A sponge}%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname bob\endcsname{\chara{bob}}%
```

So, your definition could be:

```latex
\let\oldcast\cast
\renewcommand*{\cast}[3]{%
  \oldCast{#1}{#2}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #3\endcsname{\chara{#1}}%
}
```

Note that in some cases (most notably commands defined with `\newcommand` and taking optional arguments, or commands defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`), the `\let\oldcast\cast` won't work the way you want. In such cases, the `letltxmacro` package can be very useful.

Also, since you are changing the syntax and semantics of `\cast`, it may be wiser to name your function differently—say, `\newcast`:

```latex
\newcommand*{\newcast}[3]{%
  \cast{#1}{#2}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #3\endcsname{\chara{#1}}%
}
```

Now to problem number 3. We need to do the dynamic command definition performed inside `\newcast` *global*. This can be done with `\gdef`. In order to be über-clean, we can additionally use `\newcommand` to make sure the command (such as `\bob`) doesn't already exist. Indeed, `\gdef` would overwrite an existing command without notice. Thus, we can do the following:

```latex
\newcommand*{\newcast}[3]{%
  \cast{#1}{#2}%
  % Print an error if the command named after #3 is already defined
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #3\endcsname{}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname #3\endcsname{\chara{#1}\ }% there is a control space
}
```

I added a control space after `\chara{#1}` because when you write for instance `\bob do a flip.`, from TeX's point of view, there is no space token after `\bob`: the space character that follows in the input stream is eaten as soon as `\bob` is turned into a control sequence token (this is during the TeX processing stage known as *tokenization*).

Finally, the same thing can also be done using `\csgdef` from the `etoolbox` package (this is syntactic sugar and behaves the same):

```latex
\csgdef{#3}{\chara{#1}\ }
```

Full code:

```latex
\documentclass{sides}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*{\stage}{\stagedir}

\title{MWE}
\author{Foo}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newcommand*{\newcast}[3]{%
  \cast{#1}{#2}%
  % Print an error if the command named after #3 is already defined
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #3\endcsname{}%
  \csgdef{#3}{\chara{#1}\ }% there is a control space before the brace
}

\begin{castpage}
\newcast{Bob SquarePants}{A sponge}{bob}
\newcast{Patrick Star}{A starfish}{pat}
\end{castpage}

\newact
\newscene
\show\bob
\stage{Opens on a black stage.}
\repl{Bob SquarePants} I will do a flip!
\stage{\bob do a flip.}
\repl{Patrick Star} Amazing!
\stage{\bob smiles and \chara{Patrick} applauds.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer I added a MWE as requested.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, that was quite important since you are using `\newcast` inside a group. The dynamic definition has to be global, then; please see the updated answer. I removed `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{libertine}` from the MWE because they are not relevant to the question; feel free to readd them on your side.

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine!  I just added added a parameter because I just want the firstname ```\newcommand*{\newcast}[4]{%
  \cast{#1\ #2}{#3}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #4\endcsname{}%
  \csgdef{#4}{\chara{#1}\ }
}```

Comment: Right, glad to hear that. Note that the reason why I used a control space instead of a space token (i.e., `{\chara{#1}\ }` instead of `{\chara{#1} }`) is that a control space always adds an interword glue (space) to the horizontal list, whereas a space token can add a glue item of varying width depending on what precedes (for instance, in English, after a sentence-ending period, the space is larger than an interword space). Normally, this only matters in corner cases where punctuation precedes the space; now, you know the difference and can choose appropriately.

Comment: In the end I use `{\chara{#1}\xspace}` from the package `xspace` because I noticed that `\bob, foo` gave the result `Bob , foo` instead of `Bob, foo`. `xspace` is able to determine is he should put a space or not https://ctan.org/pkg/xspace

Comment: Hmm, right. I was hoping no such use case would be sensible, but apparently you have one. I'd suggest reading [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/73317) from `xspace`'s original author. In short, maybe you should consider handling this manually, i.e. writing `\bob\ ` or `\bob,` in the script, depending on the particular sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The command `\cast` takes *one* argument and does nothing at all with the first argument except typesetting it as if it were a section title. What *seems* to be a second argument is just the text of the “section”.

If you type

```latex
\begin{castpage}
\cast{Bob SquarePants} A sponge
\end{castpage}
```

there would be no difference at all.

The command `\chara` just typesets its argument in small caps. Whether you have used `\cast{Patrick Star}{A starfish}` or not, typing `\chara{Patrick}` will do its work as defined.

There is no connection whatsoever between the argument of `\chara` and anything that appears in `castpage`.

You can simply do `\newcommand{\bob}{\chara{Bob}}` in the document preamble and use

```
\stagedir{\bob\ do a flip}
```

---

Here's a way to avoid code duplication. You input character data with a key-value syntax.

```latex
\documentclass{sides}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{xparse,xspace}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { misterjack/cast }
 {
  shortname .tl_set:N = \l__misterjack_cast_shortname_tl,
  fullname  .tl_set:N = \l__misterjack_cast_fullname_tl,
  char      .code:n = \misterjack_cast_full:nV { #1 } \l__misterjack_cast_fullname_tl,
  nick      .code:n = \misterjack_cast_short:nV { #1 } \l__misterjack_cast_shortname_tl,
  desc      .tl_set:N = \l__misterjack_cast_desc_tl,
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \misterjack_cast_full:nn
 {
  \cs_new:cpn { #1 } { \repl { #2 } \xspace }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \misterjack_cast_full:nn { nV }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \misterjack_cast_short:nn
 {
  \cs_new:cpn { #1 } { \chara { #2 } \xspace }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \misterjack_cast_short:nn { nV }

\NewDocumentCommand{\Cast}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { misterjack/cast } { #1 }
  \cast{\l__misterjack_cast_fullname_tl} \l__misterjack_cast_desc_tl
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{castpage}
\Cast{
  fullname=Bob SquarePants,
  desc=A sponge,
  shortname=Bob,
  char=Bob,
  nick=bob,
}
\Cast{
  fullname=Patrick Star,
  desc=A starfish,
  shortname=Patrick,
  char=Pat,
  nick=pat,
}
\Cast{
  fullname=Mr.~Krab,
  desc=A crab,
  shortname=Mr.~Krab,
  char=Krab,
  nick=krab,
}
\end{castpage}

\Bob Plop!

\stagedir{\bob do a flip.}

\stagedir{\krab grumbles.}

\end{document}
```

The strings for the abbreviated input are arbitrary (but should contain only ASCII characters).

[image]