# Using abbreviation commands in glosses

Tags: linguistics, xspace, cgloss4e

The package `xspace` allows for the definition of abbreviations like `\NOM`:

```
\newcommand{\NOM}{\textsc{nom}\xspace}
```

`\xspace` makes it possible to use `\NOM`in the text without a `{}`following the `\NOM`. Otherwise the `\NOM` would eat the white space following the command.

I would like to have this behavior in glosses set with the `langsci-gb4e` package and wonder if this is possible. Somehow the `\xspace` seems to cause strange effects here. It seems to be interpreted as one word with the following word.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{langsci-gb4e,xspace}

\newcommand{\NOM}{\textsc{nom}\xspace}

\begin{document}

\ea
\gll der      Mann\\
     the.\NOM man\\
\z

\ea
\gll der      Mann\\
     the.\NOM{} man\\
\z


\end{document}
```

[image]

`\gll` the glossing command calls `\twosent`, which does some magic that I do not understand ... The code is originally coming from `cgloss4e`.

```
\gdef\twosent#1\\ #2\\{% #1 = first line, #2 = second line 
  \getwords(\lineone,\eachwordone)#1 \\%
  \getwords(\linetwo,\eachwordtwo)#2 \\%
  \loop\lastword{\eachwordone}{\lineone}{\wordone}%
     \lastword{\eachwordtwo}{\linetwo}{\wordtwo}%
     \global\setbox\gline=\hbox{\unhbox\gline
                                \hskip\glossglue
                                \vtop{\box\wordone   % vtop was vbox
                                      \nointerlineskip
                                      \box\wordtwo
                                     }%
                               }%
     \testdone
     \ifnotdone
  \repeat
  \egroup % matches \bgroup in \gloss
\gl@stop}
```

Comment: `xspace` inserts a space into the output,  using `\space` which is simply another macro and gobbles the following space. But the glossing macros depend on spaces *in the input* and so you must always either put braces around gloss words that contain macros or add `{}`. There's no way around this.

Comment: I added the xspace tag and I'll add a link to by far the highest voted answer in that tag https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/1090  If xspace is convenient in simple cases, perhaps use it but if it is complicated to add then not using it is probably the best idea

Comment: as @AlanMunn says this isn't really feasible, xspace doesn't work by expansion, so no amount of `\expandafter` will get it to add a space character before you need one for `\getwords`

Comment: Thanks! Too bad ...

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression can convert `.nom` to `.NOM`:

[image: Using regex]

It means wrapping the gll/glt/etc in a command so the regex can get at it, though.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}
%--------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand { \glsm } { +m } { 

        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }

%    .text  >  .{{\posformat text}}
        \regex_replace_all:nnN
                { (\.)(\w+) }
                { \1 \cB\{\cB\{ \c{posformat} \2 \cE\}\cE\} }
                \l_tmpa_tl

        \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl

}

\NewDocumentCommand { \glsmm } { +m } { 

        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }

%    x.text  >  x.{{\posformat text}}
        \regex_replace_all:nnN
                { (\.)(\w+) }
                { \1 \cB\{\cB\{ \c{posformat} \2 \cE\}\cE\} }
                \l_tmpa_tl

%    [space].text  >  [space]text
        \regex_replace_all:nnN
                { (\s\.)(.) }
                { \ \2 }
                \l_tmpa_tl

        \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl

}


%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \posformat } { } { 
            \scshape
}
%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \setposformat } { m } { 
            \renewcommand{\posformat}{#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
Original:
\ea
\gll der      Mann\\
     the.nom man\\
\z

\bigskip
Small caps:
\ea
\glsm{%
\gll der      Mann\\
     the.nom man\\
}
\z

\bigskip
SC, blue, bold, sans
\setposformat{\scshape\bfseries\color{blue}\sffamily}
\ea
\glsm{%
\gll der      Mann\\
     the.nom man\\
}
\z
\bigskip
\ea
    \glsm{%
\gll    kma t'-əlčqu-(ɣ)in\\ 
 .1sg  .1sg.sub-see-.2sg.obj\\
\glt `I saw you.' (S1:71)
        }
\z

\bigskip
No initial dot
\ea
    \glsmm{%
\gll    kma t'-əlčqu-(ɣ)in\\ 
 .1sg  .1sg.sub-see-.2sg.obj\\
\glt `I saw you.' (S1:71)
        }
\z


\end{document}
```