# LaTeX3: Add explicit space after macro

Tags: expl3

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_new:N \my_str
\str_set:Nn \my_str {Test}

\cs_new:Nn \my_printer:x { \sys_shell_now:n { echo ~ #1 ~ > ~ output } }

% \my_printer:n {This ~ is ~ a ~ test}

\my_printer:n {\my_str ~ another ~ word}

\begin{document}
    MWE
\end{document}

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Even though I always added an explicit (non-ignored) space between the words for the argument of `\my_printer:n`, the second case writes `Got 'Testanother word'` rather than `Got 'Test another word'` to the `output` file. In the example without the macro in the argument, everything works as expected.

If I encountered macros eating spaces in regular LaTeX, I would simply add `{}` to the end of the macro, ensuring it does not eat the following space as its argument. However, when attempting that within `expl3` the braces are actually printed as plain characters.

I also tried explicitly using `\use_str:N` to get the string's value, but the result is the same.

What is the necessary trick to prevent `\my_str` from eating up the following spaces?

EDIT:

It turned out that the regular `\my_str{}` approach works fine for my MWE, but it doesn't work in non-typesetting contexts as e.g. shell-escape (in which case the behavior is as I described it).

EDIT2:

Adapted MWE to actually reflect my problem

Comment: `\c_space_str`, or a brace group as you would use normally too.

Comment: `\c_space_str` doesn't seem to exist. But `\c_space_tl` does the trick. With brace-group you mean `{\my_str} ...`? If so, this appeared to have the same issue as `\my_str{}`: The braces are printed verbatim.

Comment: yes sorry, I meant tl and `\my_str{}` works fine in your example. Btw: you should follow the naming convention of expl3. Your variable e.g. should be called `\l_raven_my_str`

Comment: Ah indeed, it does. Then the `\my_str{}` variant jsut didn't work in my actual use-case, but in my MWE it did work. In my actual example, I am passing the argument to `\sys_shell_now:n` and apparently somewhere along that way the rules appear to change... With regards to the naming scheme: Yes I do that in my actual code. I only omitted it in my MWE for brevity.

Comment: In `\ExplSyntaxOn` a `~` is the same as a space would otherwise be, and just like the normal rules for spaces, they are ignored after control words by TeX. A `~` there is not the same non-breakable explicit space it would be inside your document.

Comment: @Raven {} are not printed verbatim here (although thy would be if you put them in a str which is for detokenized strings as for `\string` where all tokens are catcode 12 or 10

Comment: Also "I only omitted it in my MWE for brevity", it's 2022, I think we all can afford the six extra-bytes :P

Comment: @Skillmon fair enough :D

Comment: Seems like an XY-question.

Comment: I fixed my MWE to actually reflect my problem. This should not invalidate the accepted answer, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The situation is exactly the same as  `\foo word` in classic TeX.

You can use `\foo{} word` or `\foo\space word` (or `\foo\c_space_tl word`)

Note in the first form the `{}` are not absorbed, they make two additional tokens. An empty group has no effect if typetting but these tokens would show up in a `\typeout` or shell escape, or other non-typesetting contexts.

Comment: `\c_space_str` does not exist - you probably also mean `\c_space_tl`, correct?

Comment: @Raven ooh blame Ulrike:-)  fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I like to add `\xspace` from package `xspace` for all my macro, that take care of typography. For example :

```
\newcommand{\arduino}{Arduino\textsuperscript{\tiny\textregistered}\xspace}
```

Note `\xspace` at the end

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `\xspace` (it just makes your output unreliable), just use correct input. Also `\xspace` wouldn't help OP in the scenario he's facing at all.

Comment: In general see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620  but in this case in a `\write`  where `{}` are writing as themselves `\xspace` will not work at all as it does not work by expansion.