# Line runs into margin when using a `newcommand` for substitution

Tags: line-breaking, customize

I defined a new command for my novel method so that I can use it all over my document (and also easily change it later when I find a better one). I noticed that this results in lines running into the margins when my method name has a specific length. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, right=4cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\methodname}{MyMethod}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy \methodname~ eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the first line first line is not rendered nicely. When I choose a longer name, at some point, the method name gets hyphenated but it still runs over the margin.

What is the source of the issue and what are the best ways to overcome it?

Comment: it was discussed below but I think the consensus is that this isn't always what one wants, for example when you have the method name at the end of the sentence

Answer (score 5):

`~_` forces a double space, and prevents a line break, neither of which you want.

Also tex can't hyphenate MyMethod by default

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, right=4cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\methodname}{My\-Method}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy \methodname\ eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your first comment might be irrelevant, the problem persists with either ~_, _ or ~. no difference here.
Your second comment does not seem to be correct. As I already said in the original question, when I choose a longer name (for example MyMethodmethod) it will it will introduce a hyphen after MyMethod. So it seems tex *is* able to hyphenate automatically but not at the correct position.

Comment: @MillaWell _look_ at the output you show  `~_`  is a double space and prevents a line break. So tex can not hyphenate but you are also preventing it breaking at the space: it has to go as far as `eir-`  before it can break. It is the main cause of your issue. I also don't know why you query my statement that tex can not hyphenate `MyMethod`. Add `\showhyphens{MyMethod MyMethodmethod}`  You will see  `MyMethod MyMethod-method` in the log showing tex finds no hyphenation points in the first and only one in the second

Comment: With the additional explanation it all makes more sense. My main issue is actually the hyphenation not the ~_. Thanks! I didn't know the `\showhyphens` command. could you point me to where one can learn about the rules?

Comment: the `~` makes it much worse though as otherwise it would have broken the line after the method name. and `~_` is also wrong in all the cases where this ends mid-line so hyphenation is not involved at all, you do not want a double space. @MillaWell

Comment: Just to be clear, you are suggesting to use `\methodname\_` to allow for tex to have more options for line breaks in comparison to `\methodname~`?

Comment: @MillaWell yes  (as long as by that you meant backslash space, not backslash underscore). Your original `\methodname~  eirmod` forces two spaces so is wrong even if no line break involved  `\methodname~eirmod` is just one space but prevents a line break so would force the line overfull even if MyMethod fitted on the line `\methodname\  eirmod` puts a normal, breakable space after the name.

Answer (score 2):

As supplement to nice @David Carlisle answer (+1):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            hmargin={2cm,=4cm}, vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\hyphenation{My-Meth-od}            % <---
\newcommand{\methodname}{MyMethod}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy \methodname\ eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree with `\hyphenation` more general than my `\-` suggestion, but trailing space is dangerous, just hope you never need to end a sentence `\methodname.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you are right. I forgot on this possibilities. I corrected this.

Comment: All possible use and styles of he `\methodname` command is unknown, but in presented case OP may risk with use `xspace` package and define new command as `\newcommand{\methodname}{MyMethod\xspace}` :-). But, better is stay on safe side and use it as suggested in your and mine answer.

Comment: brilliant package, [xspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620) I wonder who wrote it? :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I know for the link and I know who are authors :-)