# How to avoid spacing issue when inserting def value in text?

Tags: spacing, variable, def

When I define a variable:

```
\def\company{ACME}
```

And use it:

```
The company \company is...
```

I usually have the trailing space eaten by the command resulting in `The company ACMEIs`

So I do the following:

```
The company \company~is...
```

Is there a better option?

Comment: Use `\company{}` instead of `\company`. It will put spaces where there is no punctuation.

Comment: use `~` if you want a no-break space, `{}` or `\ ` otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Zxcvasdf already explained, you can use `\company{}` instead of `\company`. If you don't want to type `{}` all the time (maybe because they are hard to type with your keyboard layout or you need `\company` very often) you can also use the `xspace` package. It provides the command `\xspace` which produces a space whenever it is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\def\company{ACME\xspace}
\begin{document}
    The company \company is great! % <- space is inserted 
    I like the company \company.   % <- no space is inserted
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Let me briefly comment on why you should *not* use `~` here for inserting a space: `~` produces a non-breaking space, i.e. there cannot be a line break between these two words. Sometimes this is good style, e.g. in `See Figure~\ref{fig}` because you do not want to have `Figure` and the referenced number in different lines, but here there is no reason why you should not allow a line break.

Comment: Note that in general `\xspace` is not recommended as there are unhandled edge cases. Even its creator recommends not using `\xpsace`. It is best to use `\company{}`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620