# Defined braced macro

Tags: macros, spacing, latex3

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}{foo}

\begin{document}

test \foo bar

test {\foo} bar

test {\foo}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

My goal is to define `\foo` in such a way that it behaves as if it was braced in text `{\foo}` in order to maintain the space before the next word or ignore it in case of punctuation. Using `\bgroup..\egroup` in declaration doesn't seem to work. Bulk check for the next character via `#1` for `\foo` is not desired because it's not versatile.

I'm curious about both plain tex and latex3 approach.

Comment: you can not do that. the space is removed parsing the name so is gone before any definition of `\foo` is consulted. But see the `xspace` package which can usually add a space back (although I don't recommend it)

Comment: note in general `\foo{}` is better than `{\foo}` unless you know `\foo` is not affected by being in a group.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle there should be definitely a way by making space an active character

Comment: oh but making space globally active without completely breaking everything is not at all trivial (several people have tried, I don't think anyone ever succeeded)

Comment: you would have to make newline active as well so code "blank line  ends paragraph" by hand, while making sure multiple consecutive spaces expand to a single space