# Replacement for \xspace with expl3

Tags: expl3, latex3, xspace

I have heard more than once that `\xspace` should not be used and does not work reliable.

To find a better solution I have found `xpeek` and tried to use the example give in the documentation.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\usepackage{xpeek}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_const:Nn \c_xsp_exceptions_tl { ,;:.!? }
\NewDocumentCommand \xsp {}
{
    \xpeek_collect_do:nn \c_empty_tl
    {
        \xpeek_if_in:NNTF \c_xsp_exceptions_tl \l_peek_token
        { } { ~ }
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\numbertext}{m}
{
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} > {12}
    { % true
        #1\xsp
    }
    { % false
        \numberstringnum{#1}\xsp
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\numbertextnoxsp}{m}
{
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} > {12}
    { % true
        #1
    }
    { % false
        \numberstringnum{#1}
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\numbertextnoxspunits}{m}
{
    \numbertextnoxsp{#1} units
}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    numberstring:
    
    \numberstringnum{13} units. \numberstringnum{13}.
    
    \bigskip
    numbertext:

    \numbertext{12}units. \numbertext{12}.
    
    \numbertext{12} units. \numbertext{12}.

    \numbertext{13}units. \numbertext{13}.

    \numbertext{13} units. \numbertext{13}.

    \bigskip
    numbertextnoxsp:

    \numbertextnoxsp{12}units. \numbertextnoxsp{12}.
    
    \numbertextnoxsp{12} units. \numbertextnoxsp{12}.

    \numbertextnoxsp{13}units. \numbertextnoxsp{13}.

    \numbertextnoxsp{13} units. \numbertextnoxsp{13}.

    \bigskip
    numbertextnoxspunits:
    
    \numbertextnoxspunits{12}. \numbertextnoxspunits{12} it is.
    
    \numbertextnoxspunits{12}. \numbertextnoxspunits{12} it is.
    
    \numbertextnoxspunits{13}. \numbertextnoxspunits{13} it is.
    
    \numbertextnoxspunits{13}. \numbertextnoxspunits{13} it is.

\end{document}
```

However, this does also not seem to work since the last two lines show different results and I would not expect them to...

Output is:

[image: example3]

Comment: What would be the reason to use `\xspace` for a command with argument?

Comment: I would want to have a space after the text if there is normal text following and no space otherwise. Like there should of course be no space after my command if the next symbol is `.` or `,`... Like with the result of `\numberstringnum` directly it should work the same way with `#1`...

Comment: It's not that xspace works unreliably, it's the concept of using heuristics for adding a space after a macro that is not recommended, regardless of implementation

Comment: @mrCarnivore You *do* get a space or not without resorting to `\xspace`. Did you bother to try?

Comment: Maybe my MWE was too short. I have extended to show the problems: if you use the function in `expl3` part there definitely is no space without \xspace or similar...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: How would I solve that problem otherwise? What are the problems with \xspace in expl3? Will it just get lost?

Comment: I explain the issues here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620 but the issue is not with the implementation it is that it is better to use correct markup than try to fix bad markup. But your command has arguments so there is no problem to solve and nothing to do

Comment: But it my command `\numbertextnoxspunits` does not work because there are no space added. That is the whole point of the question...

Comment: So your suggestion is: just use `\xspace` in my expl3 code (in my case in `\\numbertextnoxsp` to make `\numbertextnoxspunits` work correctly? I mainly do not understand why everybody is going crazy for me using `\xspace` all the time and not see the problem...

Comment: Apparently it is since the code in `\numbertextnoxspunits` does not result in any spaces before the word `units`...

Comment: but that is like saying it is a problem that there is no space in `helloworld`, if you want a space after `\numbertextnoxspunits{13}` use a space. you can not simply use a space after a command with no arguments as spaces are dropped, that is what xspace tries to solve

Comment: But when would there be a need / user for \xspace following that logic?

Comment: xspace saves you using `\ ` after commands like `\LaTeX` that have no arguments. Commands with arguments have no problem to solve

Comment: I will extensively test and revisit my current understanding to better grasp if and when \xspace might be necessary. Thank you for your patience and input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason whatsoever for using `\xspace` or variant thereof at the end of a command with arguments.

There is little reason for `\xspace` after commands without argument either, but that's a different game.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\numbertext}{m}
{
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} > {12}
    { % true
        #1
    }
    { % false
        \numberstringnum{#1}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

numberstring:

\numberstringnum{13} units. \numberstringnum{13}.

\bigskip
numbertext:

\numbertext{12}units. \numbertext{12}.

\numbertext{12} units. \numbertext{12}.

\numbertext{13}units. \numbertext{13}.

\numbertext{13} units. \numbertext{13}.
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there something unexpected?

Well you added

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\numbertextnoxspunits}{m}
{
    \numbertextnoxsp{#1} units
}
```

and complain that there's no space in output after the number. Well there is NO space in the definition, because inside `\ExplSyntaxOn` spaces are ignored. You want

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\numbertextnoxspunits}{m}
{
    \numbertextnoxsp{#1}~units
}
```

because in that context `~` stands for a space token.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will extensively test and revisit my current understanding to better grasp if and when \xspace might be necessary.