Information about surrounding text
I'm trying to define a command which raises an issue about spaces.
Basically, I want to have a single command for these two :
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Cinf}{$C^\infty$ }
\newcommand{\Cinfdot}{$C^\infty$}

\begin{document}

The function $f$ is \Cinf and that's all. The function $f$ is \Cinf. The function $f$ is \Cinfdot and that's all. The function $f$ is \Cinfdot.

\end{document}

The first one puts a space before the following text, the second one doesn't, and I use it before a dot or a comma.
I'm willing to use the ifthen package, but I don't know how to get the information "it's a dot or a comma after the text". That would also be simpler if LaTeX took into account the fact that I put a space after calling my or not.

You could use xspace package but it's better just to use the standard markup such as \Cinf{} and or \Cinf\ and. LateX does take into account the space in the source, if it were not there you would have \Cinfand which would be an undefined command. So a space after a command word is always taken as the terminator of the command, and so is not used to typeset space inthe output.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620

Thanks! I've declared my question as a duplicate now.
