\unskip but add space at the end of macro if there was one
I am trying to define \obracket and \cbracket which I want to use to bracket parts of texts, either full sentences or parts of a sentence.
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\obracket}{[\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\cbracket}{]}

\begin{document}

Some text.
\obracket
Bracketed text.
\cbracket
More text.

Another \obracket example\cbracket.

\end{document}

Current output:
Some text. [Bracketed text. ]More text.
Another [example].

What I would like is:
Some text. [Bracketed text.] More text.
Another [example].

I cannot simply add \unskip at the start of the definition of \cbracket, since this would simply remove the space (leading to text.]More). What I would like is that if there is a space to be unskipped, it is moved to the end of the macro. However, I cannot universally add a \space at the end, because \cbracket may appear before punctuation where no space should be added (second example). How to do this?

And what should happen with example\cbracket and more text? How should the code detect if there is a space needed or not?  Personally I would simply use correct input like \bracketed{some text} and not try to be too clever in space detection.

@UlrikeFischer I would use example \cbracket and more text. The reason I don't use a group or environment is that this is for marking parts of text that have been modified, and these parts can begin in one group in the actual text and end in another.

You could look at xspace  package but I would not. the fact that the space after \cbracket is absorbed is not due to anything in that command it is just general tex syntax, so I would say it is a markup error: the input should have been \cbracket{} and more just as you have to use {} or \  if you have \LaTeX is something and want a space before is

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620

@DavidCarlisle thanks, that would qualify as an answer. Assuming that it is not possible to check whether \unskip did remove any tokens, \xspace probably comes closest to what I am (or was, given the drawbacks) looking for.

oh you can check you could use \@bsphack and \@esphack which is what \label an d\index etc use to mean a space before or after the command is merged to a single space after, however they have arguments so do not drop spaces after the command, so even if you checked (classically using \lastskip or better with etex using \lastnodetype then you still don't know whether there was a trailing space that has been lost due to tex parsing

I'm going with xspace as suggested by David Carlisle:
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\cbracket}{\unskip]\xspace}

Note that xspace has significant drawbacks. I only use this because this is, as explained in the comments, a temporary stage in the document where I have to mark changes. In the final document these macros will be removed, so if there are any cases where xspace fails, it won't do too much harm.
(I couldn't get \@bsphack and \@esphack to work as needed, but that will most definitely have to do with my lack of experience.)
